# How to execute powershell/cmd commands using gnuwin32 Makefiles?

Tags: windows, powershell, makefile, gnu-make

I try to use commands like curl, rm, start in makefiles in Windows using the following makefile processor: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

It does not seem to be possible, rather it seems like I am very limited with the commands. Which ways are there to extend my set of commands?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: That's a very old version of GNU make.  You can build the latest version from source very easily for yourself, or you can get a newer version pre-built from Eli Zaretskii's ezwinports project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/?source=navbar

Comment: thanks for information - I appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* you're content with a ***Windows-only* solution**, you can make do with invoking `powershell.exe` directly from your `Makefile`, as in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697219/45375).

However, **I strongly suggest avoiding Unix-like PowerShell *aliases*** such as `curl` for `Invoke-WebRequest` and `rm` for `Remove-Item`, because while their purpose is similar in the abstract, their **syntax is generally very different**. Just **use PowerShell's *native command names* to avoid ambiguity**.

Note that using `Shell := <default shell executable>` appears to be ignored by the Windows port of `make` you link to.

---

**If you want *cross-platform compatibility*:**

- either: **Use [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)**, which offers you a choice of Linux distros in which both `make` *and* the standard Unix utilities are natively available - you then need neither `cmd.exe` nor PowerShell.
- and/or: **Use [PowerShell *Core*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)** and invoke your commands as follows:

  ```
  pwsh -noprofile -command <your command>
  ```

  - In a cross-platform solution that uses WSL on Windows, you can simplify invocations by declaring `SHELL := pwsh -NoProfile` at the top of the `MakeFile`, after which you can invoke PowerShell (Core) commands directly.

Comment: Thanks for the further suggestions, maybe I will go with Powershell Core, because of the subjectively more intuitive command structure and because a Linux dependency (even if it is only WSL) would definitively not be appropriate at the current use case. I removed the command.

Comment: A late warning from someone who was bitten by Powershell: there is no real "compatibility". Powershell fails e.g. to correctly parse a command line to `gcc` when you try to give a `-DTMSTMP=1553521024.52` and leaves you with the completely unintelligible error `.52 file not found`. I quit the idea of using Powershell entirely for such purposes, its just too different from a Unix shell to make compatibility a valuable target.

Comment: @Vroomfondel, yes, that behavior - a [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291) - is unfortunate; the workaround is to quote the argument (`'-DTMSTMP=1553521024.52'`). There's another pitfall: arguments with embedded double quotes aren't passed correctly - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375). On balance, PowerShell is vastly superior to other shells, but I agree that such bugs need to be fixed sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the power of powershell by prefixing the corresponding commands with powershell.

Example:

```
.PHONY: psStuff

psStuff:
    powershell <your command>
    powershell curl google.de
    powershell rm -r folder
    powershell start yourwebsite.de
```

Comment: I don't use Windows much but does it work to set the `SHELL` variable to `powershell` (perhaps with an appropriate path?)

Comment: @MadScientist: Good suggestion, but it seems that  `SHELL`  is ignored altogether in this Windows port of `make`.

Comment: actually, I was looking for a Windows only solution, more specifically I only wanted to break out of the limited and (undocumented?) capabilities of wingnu32. So this was a solution to that :)