# pwsh -Command is removing quotation marks

Tags: powershell

**In pwsh call the following:**

```
Write-Host '{"drop_attr": "name"}'
```

Result ok:

```
{"drop_attr": "name"}
```

**Now do the same via pwsh:**

```
pwsh -Command Write-Host '{"drop_attr": "name"}'
```

Result is missing quotation marks and square brackets?

```
drop_attr: name
```

Comment: May be [related](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) issue!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**:

- **PowerShell 7.3.0 *mostly* fixed the problem, with *selective exceptions* on *Windows*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for details.
- For cross-version, cross-edition code, the `Native` module discussed at the bottom may still be of interest.

---

Unfortunately, **PowerShell's handling of passing arguments with embedded `"` chars. to *external programs*** - which includes PowerShell's own CLI (`pwsh`) - is **fundamentally broken** (and always has been), **up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x**:

**You need to manually `\`-escape `"` instances** embedded in your arguments in order for them to be correctly passed through to external programs (which *happens to be* PowerShell in this case as well):

```bash
# Note: The embedded '' sequences are the normal and expected
#       way to escape ' chars. inside a PowerShell '...' string.
#       What is *unexpected* is the need to escape " as \"
#       even though " can normally be used *as-is* inside a '...' string.
pwsh -Command ' ''{\"drop_attr\": \"name\"}'' '
```

Note that I'm assuming your intent is to pass a JSON string, hence the inner `'' ... ''` quoting (escaped single quotes), which ensures that `pwsh` ultimately sees a single-quoted string (`'...'`). (No need for an explicit output command; PowerShell *implicitly* prints command and expression output).

Another way to demonstrate this on Windows is via the standard `choice.exe` utility, repurposed to simply print its `/m` (message) argument (followed by verbatim `[Y,N]?Y`):

```bash
# This *should* preserve the ", but doesn't as of v7.2
PS> choice /d Y /t 0 /m '{"drop_attr": "name"}'
{drop_attr: name} [Y,N]?Y      # !! " were REMOVED

# Only the extra \-escaping preserves the "
PS> choice /d Y /t 0 /m '{\"drop_attr\": \"name\"}'
{"drop_attr": "name"} [Y,N]?Y  # OK
```

---

Note that **from *inside* PowerShell, you can avoid the need for `\`-escaping, if you call `pwsh` with a *script block* (`{ ... }`)** - but that **only works when calling PowerShell itself, *not other external programs***:

```bash
# NOTE: Works from PowerShell only.
pwsh -Command { '{"drop_attr": "name"}' }
```

---

**Background info on PowerShell's broken handling of arguments with embedded `"` in external-program calls**, as of PowerShell 7.2.1:

- [This GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) contains background information.
- [GitHub issue #1995](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995) discusses the problem and the details of the broken behavior as well as manual workarounds are summarized in [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995#issuecomment-562334606); the **state of the discussion as of PowerShell [Core] 7** seems to be:

  - [SEE UPDATE AT THE TOP] **A fix is being considered as an [experimental feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_features), which *may* become an official feature, in v7.3 at the earliest**. Whether it will become a regular feature - i.e whether the *default* behavior will be fixed or whether the fix will require opt-in or even if the feature will become official at all - remains to be seen.

    - Fixing the default behavior would substantially break backward compatibility; as of this writing, this has never been allowed, but a discussion as to whether to allow breaking changes in the future and how to manage them has begun: see [GitHub issue #13129](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13129).
  - See [GitHub PR #14692 for the relevant experimental feature](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/14692), which, however, as of this writing is missing vital accommodations for batch files and `msiexec`-style executables on Windows - see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143).
- In the meantime, you can use the **PSv3+ `ie` helper function** from the  **[`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native)** (in PSv5+, install with `Install-Module Native` from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Native)), which internally **compensates for all broken behavior** and allows passing arguments as expected; e.g.,
  `ie pwsh -Command ' ''{"drop_attr": "name"}'' '` would then work properly.
  `ie` is a ***cross-edition*, *forward-compatible* solution** (i.e. it also work in PowerShell (Core) 7.3+), and also compensates for the behaviors with certain types of CLIs that were *not* fixed in v7.3+.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.  Are you in Windows or Unix?

```
pwsh -c "[pscustomobject]@{drop_attr='name'} | convertto-json -compress"

{"drop_attr":"name"}
```

Comment: Thanks I am on MacOS, and I got it working in one line

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use "encoded commands".

```
> $cmd1 = "Write-Host '{ ""description"": ""Test program"" }'"
> pwsh -encoded ([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd1)))
{ "description": "Test program" }
```

Comment: If you're calling _from PowerShell_, `pwsh -Command { Write-Host '{ "description": "Test program" }' }` gives you this ability for free  (uses `-EncodedCommad` behind the scenes).