# Is there a way to escape quotes in ripgrep for MS Windows (Powershell or CMD)?

Tags: powershell, cmd, ripgrep

I want to find a string `"Hello` (Hello starts with double quote) in text files using `ripgrep`.

Normally, in Bash or ZSH, this would work by escaping with backslash or surrounding with single quote:

```
rg \"Hello
rg '"Hello'
```

However, in MS Windows (Powershell and CMD), I've tried these but none of these worked:

```
rg \"Hello
rg '"Hello'
rg `"Hello
rg '`"Hello'
```

Is there any way to escape single or double quotes using ripgrep in MS Windows?

Comment: What's stopping you from using built-in Windows methodology and/or tools instead of ripgrep?

Comment: @Compo: One compelling reason to use ripgrep is its speed; another is its friendly output formatting (highlighting of the matching line parts). While `Select-String` in PowerShell 7.0 now has such highlighting too, it is much slower. Using `Select-String` from within PowerShell would avoid the escaping headaches, but you'd face the same ones if you were to call `findstr.exe` (whose regex support is poor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verbatim string `"Hello` must ultimately be passed as `\"Hello` to `rg` (`"\"Hello"` would work too). That is, **the verbatim `"` char.  must be `\`-escaped**:

From **`cmd.exe`**:

```
rg \^"Hello
```

`^`, `cmd.exe`'s escape character, ensures that the `"` is treated verbatim and is removed by `cmd.exe` before calling `rg`.
Note that `^` isn't strictly necessary here, but it prevents the `"` from being considered the start of a double-quoted argument, which could make a difference if there were additional arguments.

From **PowerShell**:

```
rg \`"Hello
```

`` ` ``, PowerShell's escape character, ensures that the `"` is treated verbatim and is removed by PowerShell before calling `rg`.

---

**Arguably, the explicit `\`-escaping shouldn't be necessary**, because it is the duty of a shell to properly pass arguments to target executables after the user has satisfied the shell's own escaping requirements (escaping the verbatim `"` with `^` in `cmd.exe`, and with `` ` `` in PowerShell).

In the context of PowerShell, this problematic behavior is summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

Note that **in PowerShell this extra escaping is only needed if you call *external programs***; it isn't needed PowerShell-*internally* - such as when you call `Select-String`, as shown in [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59573870/45375).

Comment: These also seems to work.  

Powershell: `rg '\"Hello'`
, CMD: `rg "\"Hello"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rg -F \"Hello`

```
   -F, --fixed-strings 
   Treat the pattern as a literal string instead of a regular expression. When this flag is used, special regular expression meta characters such as .(){}*+ do not
   need to be escaped.

   This flag can be disabled with --no-fixed-strings.
```

Comment: Thanks. This works in `cmd`.  It doesn't work in powershell (and not sure why)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in powershell you might as well do:

```
get-childitem file | select-string '"hello'

file:1:"hello
```