# MSDEPLOY powershell script parameters does not work

Tags: powershell, cmd, msdeploy

I am trying to deploy a site (basically a zip file) from my machine to a remote machine. I was testing the same before I implement the actual remote deployment and I was working to the msdeploy command line code using powershell.

Later I will configure this code in C# language and execute it that will automate the deployment.

Right now , I am facing the error called

```
$msdeploy = "C:\\Program Files\\IIS\\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\msdeploy.exe"
            $package = "C:\Deploy\Test\Test.zip"
            $compname = "test_vm02"
            $appname = "Default Web Site/Test"
            $appvalue = "Test\"
            $md = $("`"{0}`" -verb:sync -source:package=`"{1}`" -dest=auto,ComputerName=`"{2}`" -setParam=name=`"{3}`",value=`"{4}`" -allowUntrusted" -f $msdeploy, $package, $compname, $appname, $appvalue)
        cmd.exe /C $md
```

This gives error saying that source does not support the parameter `'Default Web Site/Test'`.`Must be one of ()`

I also replaced the default web site to `IIS Web Application Name`  which in this case also did not work and threw the same error.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell's handling of quotes in arguments passed to external programs is [fundamentally broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)**, but things get more complicated if there's another level of quoting involved, as in your *indirect* call to `msdeploy.exe` via `cmd.exe`.

**There is usually no reason to call external programs via `cmd /c`; instead, call them *directly from PowerShell***, which, if the program name is *quoted*  or given via a *variable*, requires prepending the command line with **`&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)**:

<sup>Note: The line-ending `` ` `` chars. are line continuations, used for readability only; ignore the broken syntax highlighting.</sup>

```
$package = 'C:\Deploy\Test\Test.zip'
$compname = 'test_vm02'
$appname = 'Default Web Site/Test'
# !! If a value ends in '\' you must *double* the '\' if the value
# !! ends up just before a " in the ultimate command line.
$appvalue = 'Test\\'

& "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" `
  -verb:sync `
  -source:package=`"$package`" `
  `-dest=auto,ComputerName=`"$compname`" `
  `-setParam=name=`"$appname`",value=`"$appValue`" `
  -allowUntrusted
```

Note the need to `` ` ``-escape the `-` before the `-dest` and `-setParam` options, which is a workaround for the bug described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11646).

Leaving the parameter names (e.g. `-source:package`) otherwise unquoted and enclosing their arguments in explicit, embedded quotes (`` `" ``) ensures that the whole token is passed through looking something like `-source:package="C:\Deploy\Test\Test.zip"`, which some programs, notably `msiexec.exe` and possibly also `msdeploy.exe`, require.

**Caveat**: If PowerShell's broken (re)quoting of arguments passed to external programs (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)) should ever get fixed (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13068#issuecomment-653526374)), this technique will *break*.

If you just used `-source:package=$package` and the value of `$package` contained embedded spaces, PowerShell would double-quote the *whole* token behind the scenes and pass something like
`"-source:package=C:\Deploy 1\Test\Test.zip"`

Programs such as `msiexec.exe` and `msdeploy.exe` *should* recognize this quoting style too, but unfortunately don't.