# Trouble running script and passing the parameter. Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with this method for launching my powershell script:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""c:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Scripts\updateM2.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

The above works.. But I would like to pass the parameter to the script...:

```
UpdateSandP
```

So where do I put this.. ?

Comment: Add your parameter arguments to the very end of the `-ArgumentList '...'` string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pwsh -Command is removing quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036580/pwsh-command-is-removing-quotation-marks)

Comment: Nope none of the above worked..I tired this and it didnt work:

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""c:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Scripts\updateM2.ps1"" UpdateSandP' -Verb RunAs}";

Comment: Can you show us the `param()` block from `updateM2.ps1`?

Comment: Yes I suspect that is the problem?....

#ENTRY POINT
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [String] $Update
)

Comment: So try adding `-Update UpdateSandP` instead of just `UpdateSandP` :)

Comment: Nope doesnt work:

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""c:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Scripts\updateM2.ps1"" -Update UpdateSandP' -Verb RunAs}";

Comment: Does it work at all (without arguments)??? Note my early referral, the command interpreter will strip your double quotes. You will need to escape them with backslashes: ` PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \""C:\Users\Ronald\OneDrive\Scripts\_Test\PowerShell\Folder with Space\test.ps1\""' -Verb RunAs}" `

Comment: Finally got it working with:


PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File """"c:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Scripts\updateM2.ps1"""" """"\UpdateSandP"""" ' -Verb RunAs}";