# Escaping quotation marks in Powershell

Tags: powershell, escaping, quotes

In Powershell, I would like to run the following command:

```
bash -c "echo 'hello world!'"
```

(I know I could use `echo` or `Write-Host` directly, but I need to use `bash -c`) and I would like `hello` to be surrounded by single quotes and `world` by double quotes. In other words, I'd like the following output:

```
'hello' "world"!
```

I should I escape those quotation marks?

Comment: But you are not running PowerShell. You are running bash.exe in a PowerShell session. That is not the same thing. To run .exe in PowerShell you must properly config the line. See this: --- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx and this --- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187651/how-to-echo-single-quote-when-using-single-quote-to-wrap-special-characters-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling a program (e.g. `bash`) "normal" rules to [escape quotation characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) don't necessarily work the "same" way. Instead of PowerShell interpreting the string, (which would normally follow "normal" quotation rules), you are passing **arguments** to the program. This is interpreted in a completely different manner.

TLDR: To escape quotation characters requires the following command:

```
bash -c "echo \'Hello\' \\\""World\\\""!"
```

Outputs:

```
'Hello' "World"!
```

Now that looks awfully complicated. So, let's break it down.

First, what is the correct command in `bash` to output the desired quotation? Let's try regular quotes:

```
HAL9256@HAL9000:~$ echo 'Hello' "World"!
Hello World!
```

No quotes. Oh yeah! I have to escape them. In `bash` I have to escape them with backslashes (`\`):

```
HAL9256@HAL9000:~$ echo \'Hello\' \"World\"!
'Hello' "World"!
```

There we have it. We have to use a single backslash to properly escape our quotes in `bash`. So let's plug that into PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> bash -c "echo \'Hello\' \"World\"!"
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Well that didn't work. Oh right, in **PowerShell** we have to escape the double quotes with backticks (`) because they are inside a set of double quotes:

```
PS C:\> bash -c "echo \'Hello\' \`"World\`"!"
'Hello' World!
```

Well, that didn't error out, but still not what we want. The quotes are still not escaped properly. Grrr. *This is where you start typing in 100 different combinations of characters to find out what the right combination is* ;-).

Or, let's go back to `bash` and figure out what may be going on. First, let's remember that the string that is being `echo`ed is being interpreted like a string. So let's put double quotes around our echo statement so that it is being treated like a string, and see what it does. Remember, what we want out of this is the output to be the same `bash` command earlier, with the backslashes:

```
HAL9256@HAL9000:~$ echo "\'Hello\' \"World\"!"
\'Hello\' "World"!
```

Well, ultimately what we want to send to `bash` is that original string with the backslashes. Here we can see that the backslashes are escaping the double quotes and disappearing. So, adding more slashes:

```
HAL9256@HAL9000:~$ echo "\'Hello\' \\"World\\"!"
\'Hello\' \World\!
```

Oh, great. We escaped the backslashes. Like Inception, keep adding escape characters till it works....

```
HAL9256@HAL9000:~$ echo "\'Hello\' \\\"World\\\"!"
\'Hello\' \"World\"!
```

There! we have our output. Now we have to enter it into PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> bash -c "echo \'Hello\' \\\"World\\\"!"
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Oh! yes the same error as before. We have to remember to escape the double quotes in PowerShell with a backtick:

```
PS C:\> bash -c "echo \'Hello\' \\\`"World\\\`"!"
'Hello' "World"!
```

Success! It only took a lot of escaping, both `bash`-wize, and PowerShell-wize. Another way, and in my opinion, easier to understand way to escape inside double quotes is to use two double quotes instead of the backtick like so:

```
PS C:\> bash -c "echo \'Hello\' \\\""World\\\""!"
'Hello' "World"!
```

Comment: On my computer, it doesn't work, I don't get any quotation marks. This is my $PSVersionTble:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.0
OS                             Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Mon Feb 10 21:08:45 PST 2020; root:xnu…
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: Nothing changes, unfortunately.

Comment: After downloading and installing WSL I realized that we aren't dealing with "typical" PowerShell quotation rules. We are dealing with the parsing and interpretation of arguments *as well*. This means you have to get a little crazy with escaping things. See edits above.

Comment: Ok... I think I got it. There cannot be a unique way of escaping quotes: in fact, if we put the whole bash command between single quotes (instead of double), we can't use the exact same quoting. My problem is that I was trying to make a function to escape quotes automatically, but passing a string to it it's not enough... I also have to tell it if the escaped string will be enclosed in single or double quotes. It works, but it's not as straightforward as I thought  :)

Answer (score 2):

[HAL9256's answer is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893041/45375), but let me try to frame the issue differently:

To get the desired verbatim output, this is what your command would need to look like *if you ran it from `bash` itself*:

```sh
# From Bash itself
$ bash -c "echo \"'hello' \\\"world\\\"!\""
'hello' "world"!
```

Bash's initial parsing of the string literal above, inside of which `\` functions as the escape character, means that the new `bash` instance sees the following *verbatim* text as its `-c` argument:
`echo "'hello' \"world\"!"`
Therefore, if you were to execute this as a command *directly* in Bash, it would yield the desired output too.

Note how the `echo` argument *as a whole* is enclosed in (initially`\`-escaped) `"..."`, for robustness: without that, if `world` were `world & space`, for instance, the command would *break*; similarly, `world      class` would turn into `world class` (normalization of whitespace due to *shell expansions*).

**The many `\` characters are needed due to *2* layers of escaping being involved**:

- Escaping for the *calling* shell (also `bash` in this example), to ensure that the input string is syntactically valid: `\"` embeds a single `"`, and `\\` a single `\`.
- Escaping for the *target* shell (`bash`), so that the *resulting* string is syntactically valid for *it*, given that the resulting string is *parsed as a command* in this case.

**Translating the command so it can be called *from PowerShell* requires adapting the *first* layer above, which means using `` ` ``, PowerShell's escape character, instead of `\`**.

A direct translation is therefore:

```sh
# SHOULD work, but DOESN'T as of PowerShell 7.0
PS> bash -c "echo `"'hello' \`"world\`"!`""
hello          # !! WRONG output.
```

Yet, if you print string literal `` "echo `"'hello' \`"world\`"!`"" `` *directly* in PowerShell, you'll see that it properly yields the *verbatim* string that `bash` needs to see, as shown above
(`echo "'hello' \"world\"!"`)

The reason it doesn't work is that **PowerShell's passing of arguments to *external programs* has always been broken with respect to *embedded double quotes***:

[This answer provides an overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375), but the short of it is, as of PowerShell 7.0:

In addition to satisfying PowerShell's *own* syntax requirements - which is enough if you call *PowerShell* commands - **you must *additionally* `\`-escape embedded `"` characters in arguments passed to *external programs***.

Therefore:

```sh
# OK, but the manual \-escaping shouldn't be necessary.
PS> bash -c "echo \`"'hello' \\\`"world\\\`"!\`""
'hello' "world"!
```

---

Why the current behavior is broken:

It is the job of a shell to pass arguments that result from the shell's own parsing *verbatim* to the target program, doing whatever is necessary *behind the scenes to ensure that* - **you shouldn't have to worry about any escaping requirements *other than PowerShell's own***:

- On Windows, out of unfortunate necessity, this means *constructing a command line behind the scenes* that *applies double-quoting and escaping as needed*; while double-quoting *is* applied by PowerShell on demand, it is the `\`-escaping of `"` chars. *embedded in arguments* that is missing.
- On Unix-like platforms, no extra effort is required: there, programs receive arguments directly as an *array* of *verbatim* values.

While the particular command discussed in this question happens to make the translation to PowerShell fairly straightforward, **there are much more insidious cases, where the additional need to `\`-escape - which is always *cumbersome* - is also *unexpected*, because *these commands work as-is in `bash` itself***:

```sh
PS> bash -c 'echo "hi, there"'
hi,   # !! " were stripped, so bash only saw `echo hi,` as the command string,
      # !! and `there` as a separate argument.
```

```sh
PS> /bin/echo '{ "foo": "bar" }' # Try to pass a JSON string
{ foo: bar } # !! BROKEN JSON
```