# Multi parameters in Powershell Bash/Zsh command

Tags: powershell, kubectl

Unable to run the following Bash/Zsh command in Powershell:

```
$KeyPath = Join-Path -Path $this.Plate -ChildPath "install/tekton.key"
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred `
    --docker-server="https://gcr.io" `
    --docker-username=_json_key `
    --docker-email="name@org.iam.gserviceaccount.com" `
    --docker-password="$(cat $KeyPath)"
```

I get error:

```
error: exactly one NAME is required, got 5
See 'kubectl create secret docker-registry -h' for help and examples
```

If I run this command directly in bash it works:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server="https://gcr.io" --docker-username=_json_key --docker-email="name@org.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --docker-password="$(cat ./tekton.key)"
```

Comment: Did you finally get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but **there are two *potential* problems**:

- **An expanded value that contains spaces causes PowerShell to double-quote the argument *as a whole*** when it rebuilds the command line behind the scenes (on Windows):

  - For instance, if `$(cat $KeyPath)` (`$(Get-Content $KeyPath)`) expands to `one two`, PowerShell passes `"--docker-password=one two"` behind the scenes, *not* `--docker-password="one two"`.
  - Whether this changes the meaning of the argument depends on how the target program parses its command line - I don't know what `kubectl` does.

    - If you do need to address this, escape the enclosing `"` (double quotes) with `` ``` (the backtick, PowerShell's escape character to make PowerShell pass your argument in the original syntax form:

      - `` --docker-password=`"$(cat ./tekton.key)`" ``
    - Note that - unlike in POSIX-like shells such as Bash and Zsh - you normally do *not* enclose a variable reference or subexpression in `"..."` in order to pass it through safely; e.g., `--foo=$someVar` or `--foo=$(Get-Date)` work fine, even if `$someVar` or the output from `Get-Date` contains spaces or wildcard characters.
- **If file `$KeyPath` contains *multiple* lines, the lines are *concatenated with spaces*** in the argument:

  - For instance, if the file contains `` "a`nb`n" `` (`` "`n" `` being a newline), PowerShell will pass
    `"--docker-password=a b`".
  - By contrast, POSIX-like shells such as Bash or Zsh will preserve the *interior* newlines, while trimming (any number of) *trailing* ones.

---

On a side note: PowerShell's handling of *embedded double-quoting* in arguments passed to external programs is broken - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).