# Using 'rm -rf' in Linux PowerShell and Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, powershell

I need to execute "rm -rf" on remote machine running Ubuntu in order to clear specified folder.
If I use command like following everything goes fine.

```
rm -rf "home/blahblah/blah"/*
```

But if I run the same command in Linux PowerShell I would get ALL files removed.
Is there any way to specify path to be handled the same way in bash and PS? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.0, you must do the following (if you want to use the external `rm` utility):

```
sh -c "rm -rf 'home/blahblah/blah'/*"
```

<sup>Note that I've switched to single-quoting (`'...'`) around the path, so I could use it inside a double-quoted (`"..."`) string. While the reverse (`'... "..."/*'`) *should* work as-is, it currently requires *additional* escaping (`'... \"...\"/*'`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).</sup>

However, if the path preceding the `/*` doesn't actually need *quoting* - notably if it doesn't contain spaces - you can simply call:

```
rm -rf home/blahblah/blah/*
```

---

You're seeing a very unfortunate difference between PowerShell (as of 7.0) and POSIX-like shells such as Bash with respect to the handling of string arguments composed of both quoted and unquoted parts.

PowerShell parses `"home/blahblah/blah"/*` as *two* arguments:

- `home/blahblah/blah` becomes the first argument, as-is in this case.
- `/*` is interpreted as the second argument, which, due to being *unquoted* and due to an *external utility* being called, triggers PowerShell's emulation of the globbing (filename expansion) behavior of POSIX-like shells, which means that *all files and directories in the root directory* are being passed as individual arguments.

Therefore, the arguments that the `rm` utility actually receives are: `-rf`, `home/blahblah/blah`, `/bin`, `/boot`, `/dev`, ... - which is clearly not the intent.

This problematic behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12647).

Passing the command to `sh`, the default shell on Unix-like platforms, instead, bypasses the problem.