# Can I transfer a PowerShell array to node.js?

Tags: node.js, arrays, powershell, parameter-passing

I want to start a node.js script with PowerShell.
The processed data should be come from an PowerShell array.

Is this possible?

Comment: i would export the data to a JSON file and then import it into whatever you want to make use of it.

Comment: Good idea, @Lee_Dailey, but you don't even need a _file_ for that: assuming the array is small enough, you can pass the JSON as an _argument_ (beware the `"`-escaping headaches); otherwise, you can _pipe_ it.

Answer (score 2):

**Using command-line *arguments*, you cannot pass an array *as such* to an external program**, such as `node`, via its CLI, as there is no such construct built in.

There are two workarounds:

- (a) Pass the array elements *as individual arguments*
- (b) Use a *custom representation* of the argument inside a *single string* argument, which the target program must parse.

---

A simple demonstration of (a):

```sh
# Construct a PowerShell array and pass its elements as individual
# arguments to an ad-hoc Node.js script:
PS> $arr = 'one', 'two'; node -pe 'process.argv.slice(1)' $arr
[ 'one', 'two' ]
```

<sup>Note: If you pass the path of a script *file*, use `2` rather than `1` as the offset, because element `1` of `argv` is then the script's path.</sup>

Note how simply passing the PowerShell `$arr` as-is made PowerShell pass its elements as individual arguments.

---

A simple demonstration of (b):

```sh
# Pass the array as a single string containing the space-separated
# elements, and convert that string to an array in JavaScript.
PS> $arr = 'one', 'two'; node -pe 'process.argv[1].split(/ /)' "$arr"
[ 'one', 'two' ]
```

- `"$arr"`, i.e. enclosing the array in `"..."`, implicitly *stringifies* it, resulting in a space-separated list of its (stringified) elements (you can change the separator via the `$OFS` preference variable).
- The JavaScript `.split()` method converts the string back to an array.

If you need to **support array elements with *embedded* spaces and possibly even data types *other than string***, a more sophisticated approach is needed.

As [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) suggests, **you can use JSON** for that:

```sh
# Construct a PowerShell array and pass it as a single argument
# in JSON form, which JavaScript can easily parse:
PS> $arr = 'one', 2; node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1])' (ConvertTo-Json $arr).Replace('"', '\"')
[ 'one', 2 ]  # Note that the numeric element was preserved as such.
```

**Note the unfortunate need to call `.Replace('"', '\"')`** on [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json)'s output in order to manually `\`-escape the `"` chars. in the JSON text, which **shouldn't be necessary**, but as of PowerShell Core 7.1 still is due to PowerShell's broken argument-passing to external programs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

---

You can **avoid the escaping headaches** if you **pass the JSON text *via the pipeline***, which the Node.js script can read via *stdin*:

```
# Construct a PowerShell array, convert it to JSON, and send it
# via the *pipeline* to the Node.js script.
# NOTE: On *Windows PowerShell*, run
#         $OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false)
#       first, to ensure that non-ASCII characters are properly encoded.
#       PowerShell [Core] v6+ already defaults to BOM-less UTF-8.
$arr = 'one', 2
ConvertTo-Json $arr |
  node -pe "JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(0).toString())"
```

The result is the same as above.

(Note that the Node.js command argument (the string passed to `-pe`) too is subject to the escaping headaches, which were avoided in this case by using `"..."` as the outer quoting and `'...'` as the inner quoting, given that `'` chars. need no escaping).

Comment: nice summary. thanks. powershell's quoting is not particularly helpful at times. i wouldn't have suspected that sending stdin would have had issues (before v6).

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @bmacnaughton. Using the pipeline / stdin should work fine in Windows PowerShell too, except that you may have to set `$OutputEncoding` first to ensure that PowerShell uses UTF-8 encoding. The last sentence in my answer was perhaps a bit confusing, so I've amended it.