# How input a file data for command in windows powershell/cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface, bcp

I am trying to run a BCP command in windows machine powershell and unable to give input from a sql file.

Below command works fine in my MAC and I am looking for the same for Windows machine.

`bcp "$(< /Users/mahendra.hegde/Desktop/input.sql)" queryout /Users/mahendra.hegde/dataout.json -c -T -S sample.env.compxyz.com`

input.sql file scripts should be passed as input to bcp command when it runs.

I tried many ways in Windows but did not work, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This is in bash on the Mac? If so, please provide a breakdown and explanation of what it's doing.

Comment: Are you just reading the content of a file? please be clear on what you want to achieve

Comment: What did you search for? ['bcp powershell'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27bcp+powershell%27&t=h_&ia=web) --- What have you tried? What happened? [• PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx). There are modules to work wiht SQL via teh MS powershellgallery.com. `Find-Module -Name '*sql*' | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: SO does have rules we are told to follow: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting):

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of this `bash` command:

```
bcp "$(< /Users/mahendra.hegde/Desktop/input.sql)" queryout
```

is this PowerShell command:

```
bcp (Get-Content -Raw C:/Users/mahendra.hegde/Desktop/input.sql) queryout
```

Both commands pass the *content* of the specified file as a single, multiline string to the `bcp` utility; see the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet's documentation.

However, as of PowerShell 7.1, due to broken passing of arguments with embedded `"` characters - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) - more work is needed if the `.sql` file contains `"` characters; in the simplest case:

```
bcp ((Get-Content -Raw C:/Users/mahendra.hegde/Desktop/input.sql) -replace '"', '\"') queryout
```