# What is the proper way to escape quotes and slashes when running a Jest test with --collectCoverageFrom from Powershell via npm scripts?

Tags: reactjs, windows, powershell, npm, jestjs

I am a React developer, and am used to running commands like the example below from Bash in Linux, but now I have to make it work in a Windows environment from Powershell:

```sh
npm test ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom='["**/ExampleComponent.tsx"]' --watch
```

The npm test script just has "jest" in it, but I need to use it via the script so that I am using the version of jest in the project, not a global.

I use this when trying to fill-in gaps in code coverage in a specific file (`ExampleComponent.tsx`), so I want Jest to reassess the coverage for just that one file when I save changes to the test file (`ExampleComponent.test.tsx` in this case).

This is what I ran in Powershell (Added the quotes in `"--"` because Powershell doesn't treat `--` as bash does, and switched from forward slash to backslash for Windows):

```
npm test "--" ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom='["**\ExampleComponent.tsx"]' --watch
```

This is how jest gets called as per the output from npm:

```
jest "ExampleComponent" "--collectCoverageFrom=[**\ExampleComponent.tsx]" "--watch"
```

In Powershell (version 7.2, if that matters), the command above doesn't restrict the coverage check to the specified file. It does only test the specified file, but the `collectCoverageFrom` option is ignored presumably because the pattern jest receives is mangled by Powershell.

How can I escape the quotes and slashes from a Powershell commandline to replicate the bash invocation at the top? Based on answers regarding escaping in Powershell, I've tried combinations of multiple backslashes and multiple quotes in a myriad of permutations, but none of them have worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

### Update as of Powershell version 7.2.1:

The triple-backslash doesn't seem to be necessary anymore; the syntax in this answer's previous version is no longer working for me. But the following works:

```
npm t "--" ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom="'[\""**/ExampleComponent.tsx\""]'"
```

Jest echoes back the same as before as mentioned below with this syntax.

### Previous version:

---

I have found a version that works:

```
npm t "--" ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom="'[\\\""**/ExampleComponent.tsx\\\""]'"
```

The command seems to be running as expected, calculating coverage for the specified file only.

Jest echoes back the command as:

```
jest "ExampleComponent" "--collectCoverageFrom='[\"**/ExampleComponent.tsx\"]'"
```

The processed version has backslashes before the double-quotes since the entire argument is already wrapped in double-quotes. I also had to change the backslash back to a forward slash.

Thanks to @mklement0 for his input in the question's comments.

Answer (score 0):

[Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119866/45375) is effective, but let me add important background information:

The **core problem** is the sad reality that **up to at least PowerShell 7.2  an *extra, manual* layer of `\` -escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to *external programs***. This *may* get fixed in a future version, which *may* require opt-in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details.

**In your *particular case***, the problem is apparently compounded by having to **perform this escaping *twice***, because *two* calls are involved: first, to `npm`, which then *relays* some of the arguments it received to `jest`.

Ultimately, **what you want `jest` to see *verbatim***, after it has parsed its own command line (on Windows) is the following string:

```
--collectCoverageFrom='["**/ExampleComponent.tsx"]'
```

As an aside: **Your `bash` command does *not* achieve that**, because the `'` have *syntactic* function (as they do in PowerShell) and are *removed* by `bash` before the resulting string is passed on.

**If the PowerShell bug *weren't* in the picture**, you'd use the following:

```sh
npm t '--' ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom='''["**/ExampleComponent.tsx"]'''
```

Note the `''` embedded in the overall `'...'` [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), which are *escaped* `'` chars. to be included *verbatim* in the string.

Alternatively, you could use `"..."` for the outer quoting, which then requires you to escaped the embedded `"` chars. as `` `" `` (or `""`<sup>[1]</sup>):

```sh
npm t '--' ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom="'[`"**/ExampleComponent.tsx`"]'"
```

Note, however, that such double-quoted strings are [*expandable* strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), i.e. subject to string interpolation. It's generally better to use verbatim strings (`'...'`) for strings that do *not* require interpolation, for conceptual clarity and to prevent potentially unwanted interpolation (not a concern here, given that the string contains no meant-to-be verbatim `$` or `` ` ``characters).

**With no bug regarding embedded `"` characters present, there is also *no* problem with *relaying* arguments - irrespective of the number of times this is performed.**

---

In fact, if you're **on PowerShell 7.2, you *can* make this work**, but only **if you explicitly enable the `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` [*experimental* feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features)**:

- `Enable-ExperimentalFeature PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`
- Then start a new session for the change to take effect.
- In the new session, run `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Standard'` so as to also apply the fix to *batch files* (`*.cmd`, `*.bat`), which is necessary because the `npm` CLI is implemented as one.

  - This unfortunate need for an *additional, per-session step* is the result of a highly unfortunate design decision to by default (value `'Windows'`) *exempt* batch files and WSH script files (JScript, VBScript) from the fix, instead of applying target scripting engine-appropriate fixes *automatically* - see the conversation in [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143#issuecomment-833568832)

Run `Disable-ExperimentalFeature PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` later to disable it again.

---

***With* the bug present:**

- The *embedded* **`"` characters** in your string **require *manual* `\`-*escaping***, due to the bug - irrespective of whether you use a `'...'` or a `"..."` string:
- If only *one* call were involved, this means:

```sh
# Note the \-escaped "
npm t '--' ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom='''[\"**/ExampleComponent.tsx\"]'''
```

This would make `npm` see the desired verbatim string.

- Because **`npm` then *relays* the argument** in question to `jest`, **an *additional* round of escaping must be applied**:

```sh
# Note the \-escaped ", preceded by an \-escaped \
npm t '--' ExampleComponent --collectCoverageFrom='''[\\\"**/ExampleComponent.tsx\\\"]'''
```

That is:

- The call to `npm` effectively turns the `\"` to `"`
- Because the argument is then *relayed* it must *again* be manually `\`-escaped, so that the `"` chars. are also preserved in the call to `jest`.
- By prepending `\\` - i.e. an *escaped* `\` to - `\"` (`\\\"`), `npm` ends up seeing *verbatim* `\"`, which, when relayed *via PowerShell*, makes `jest` see just `"`, as desired.

---

<sup>[1] While `""` works fine inside `"..."`, it works *only* there. By contrast, `` `" `` uses PowerShell's *general* escape character, the backtick (`` ` ``) - and having to remember only that *one* character, irrespective of context, reduces the memory burden for the user.</sup>