# Powershell script is failing when files with a single quote are passed through script. Alternate batch file is also failing with & and ! characters

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line, escaping

This is a deceptively complex issue, but I'll do my best to explain the problem.

I have a simple wrapper script as follows called `VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1`:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory,Position = 0)]
    [String[]]
    $Path,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]
    $FilenamesOnly,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]
    $Quotes
)

if($FilenamesOnly){
    Copy-PathToClipboard -Path $Path -FilenamesOnly
}else{
    Copy-PathToClipboard -Path $Path
}
```

`Copy-PathToClipboard` is just a function I have available that copies paths/filenames to the clipboard. It's irrelevant to the issue, just assume it does what it says.

The way the wrapper is called is through the Windows right click context menu. This involves creating a key here: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\`.

Mine looks like this:
[image: Regedit]

The command is as follows:

```
"C:\Tools\scripts\BIN\SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe" -q:' "-c:pwsh -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -Command "C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1" -Path $files" "%1"
```

And similarly for the "Copy as Filename":

```
"C:\Tools\scripts\BIN\SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe" -q:' "-c:pwsh -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -Command "C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1" -FilenamesOnly -Path $files" "%1"
```

I am using a tool here called [SingleInstanceAccumulator](https://github.com/Beej126/SingleInstanceAccumulator). This allows me to pass multiple selected files to a *single* instance of PowerShell. If I didn't use this program and ran my command with multiple files selected it would launch multiple instances of PowerShell for each file selected. It's the next best thing to creating your own shell extension and implementing IPC etc.

This has been working great until today when I encountered a file with a single quote in its filename (I.E.`testing'video.mov`) and the entire script failed. It's failing because the delimiter I'm using with SingleInstanceAccumulator is also a single quote and PowerShell sees no matching quote... thus errors out.

I could fix this if my variables were static by just doubling up the offending single quote, but since my parameters are files I have no opportunity to escape the single quote beyond renaming the file itself ... which is a non-solution.

So now I have no clue how to handle this.

**My first try at solving the problem was as such:**

---

1. Create a batch file and redirect my registry command to it.
2. Change the SingleInstanceAccumulator delimiter to '/' (All files will be separated by a forward slash.)
3. Replace the offending single quote to two single quotes.
4. Replace the '/' delimiters with single quotes.
5. Finally pass the whole argument list back to Powershell.

This image demonstrates how the above process looks:

[image: Command Parsing]

This is the batch file's code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: This script is needed to escape filenames that have 
:: a single quote ('). It's replaced with double single
:: quotes so the filenames don't choke powershell
:: echo %cmdcmdline%

set "fullpath=%*"

echo Before 
echo !fullpath!
echo ""

echo After
set fullpath=%fullpath:'=''%
set fullpath=%fullpath:/='%
echo !fullpath!

:: pwsh.exe -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command "%~dpn0.ps1 -Path !fullpath!

pause
```

Once I got that wired up I started celebrating ... until I hit a file with an ampersand (&) or an exclamation point (!). Everything fell apart again. I did a whole bunch of google-fu with regards to escaping the & and ! characters but nothing suggested worked at all for me.

If I pass `'C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\testing&video.mov'` into my batch file, I get `'C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\testing` back.

It truncates the string at the exact position of the ampersand.

I feel like there has to be a way to solve this, and that I'm missing something stupid. If I echo `%cmdcmdline%` it shows the full commandline **with** the &, so it's available somehow with that variable.

In conclusion: I'm sorry for the novel of a post. There is a lot of nuance in what I'm trying to accomplish that needs to be explained. My questions are as follows:

1. Can I accomplish this with Powershell only and somehow pre-escape single quotes?
2. Can I accomplish this with a batch file, and somehow pre-escape `&` and `!` (and any other special characters that would cause failure)?

Any help at all would be hugely appreciated.

### Edit1:

---

So in the most hideous and hackish way possible, I managed to solve my problem. But since it's so horrible and I feel horrible for doing it I am still looking for a proper solution.

Basically, to recap, when I do either of these variable assignments:

```
set "args=%*"
set "args=!%*!"
echo !args!
```

`&` and `!` characters still break things, and I don't get a full enumeration of my files. Files with `&` get truncated, etc.

But I noticed when I do:

```
set "args=!cmdcmdline!"
echo !args!
```

I get the full commandline call with all special characters retained:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboardTest.bat" /C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\KylieCan't.mov/,/C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\The !Rodinians - Future Forest !Fantasy - FFF Trailer.mov/,/C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\Yelle - Je Veu&x Te Voir.mov/,/C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\Erik&Truffaz.mov/,/C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\my_file'name.mov/,/C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Testing\Video Files\MOV Batch\testing&video.mov/"
```

So what I did was simply strip out the initial `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboardTest.bat"` part of the string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "args=!cmdcmdline!"
set args=!args:C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe=!
set args=!args: /c ""C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.bat" =!
set args=!args:'=''!
set args=!args:/='!
set args=!args:~0,-1!

echo !args!

pwsh.exe -noprofile -noexit -command "%~dpn0.ps1 -Path !args!
```

And... it works flawlessly. It handles any crazy character I throw at it without needing to escape anything. I know It's totally the most degenerate garbage way of approaching this, but not finding a solution anywhere leads me to desperate measures. :)

I am probably going to make the string removal a bit more universal since it literally breaks if I change the filename.

I am still VERY much open to other solutions should anyone know of a way to accomplish the same thing in a more elegant way.

Comment: I'm not at all sure how you expect that something can correctly use the doublequotes in `"C:\Tools\scripts\BIN\SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe" -q:' "-c:pwsh -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -Command "C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1" -Path $files" "%1"` and `"C:\Tools\scripts\BIN\SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe" -q:' "-c:pwsh -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -Command "C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1" -FilenamesOnly -Path $files" "%1"` in the manner intended. You have nested doublequotes, which I would assume would require escaping for the string positions to be understood.

Comment: They don't need escaping. `"C:\Tools\scripts\BIN\SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe" -q:' "-c:pwsh -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -Command "C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1" -Path $files" "%1"` 

works absolutely fine, except for filenames or directories with a single quote.

Here's a quick mockup that breaks the call down into chunks:
https://i.imgur.com/Wi2L2Ly.png



`

Comment: If you say it works, then that's fine, all I'm saying is that I see a clearly defined single doublequoted element `"-c:pwsh -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -Command "`.

Comment: The Unicode standard names `"` a QUOTATION MARK and `'` an APOSTROPHE. We should deprecate "double quote" and  "single quote" terminology. Just saying "quote it" is ambiguous.

Comment: @lit Fair point. I'll be less ambiguous with my terminology.

Comment: @Jay, does `-q:'` specify the separator used to separate multiple paths, passed as `%1`? Is it an option to modify the `.ps1` files to use a different separator?

Comment: @mklement0 `-q:quote (default is ")` and `-d:delimiter (default: ,)` See the reference here: https://github.com/Beej126/SingleInstanceAccumulator

In my first example when I made the post, I set `-q:` to an apostrophe `'`

Comment: I see. I notice that there's an `-f` option that saves the file paths to a temp file and passes that temp file's path as `$files`. If you can modify your `.ps1` files to read the paths from that file instead, your quoting headaches would go away.

Comment: @mklement0 I thought of doing that, but it feels kind of dirty creating files on disk when performing a simple operation like copying filenames. Maybe you're right. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: . As long as the temp file is automatically cleaned up, I think it's at least a _conceptually_ clean solution. While it may technically be _slower_, I don't think that'll be noticeable to the human observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A **fully robust solution** based on PowerShell's **`-Command` (`-c`)** [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) parameter that can handle `'` characters in paths as well as `$` and `` ` `` ones requires a fairly elaborate workaround, unfortunately:<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Use an aux. `cmd.exe` call that echoes the `$files` macro as-is and *pipe* that to `pwsh.exe`; make `SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe` *double-quote* the individual paths (as it does by default), but  use *no* delimiter (`d:""`) in order to effectively output a string in the form `"<path 1>""<path 2>""...`
  - Make `pwsh.exe` reference the piped input via the automatic `$input` variable and split it into an array of individual paths by `"` (removing empty elements that are a side effect of splitting with `-ne ''`). The necessity for providing the paths *via the pipeline* (stdin) is discussed in more detail in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70367736/45375).
  - The resulting array can safely be passed to your scripts.
- Also, enclose the entire `-Command` (`-c`) argument passed to `pwsh.exe` in `\"...\"` inside the `"-c:..."` argument.

  - Note: You *may* get away without doing this; however, this would result in *whitespace normalization*, which (however unlikely) would alter a file named, say, `foo    bar.txt` to `foo bar.txt` (the run of multiple spaces was normalized to a single space).
  - *Escaping* `"` characters as `\"` is necessary for PowerShell's `-Command` (`-c`) [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) parameter to treat them *verbatim*, as part of the PowerShell code to execute that is seen *after* initial command-line parsing, during which any *unescaped* `"` characters are stripped.

Therefore, the first command stored in the registry should be (adapt the second one analogously; note that there must be *no space* between the `echo $files` and the subsequent `|`):

```sh
"C:\Tools\scripts\BIN\SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe" -d:"" "-c:cmd /c echo $files| pwsh.exe -noprofile -c \"& 'C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1' -Path ($input -split '\\\"' -ne '')\"" "%1"
```

**Note**:

If you modified your scripts to accept the paths as *individual* arguments rather than as an *array*, a **much simpler solution via the `-File` CLI parameter** (rather than `-Command` (`-c`)) is possible. This could be as simple as decorating the `$Path` parameter declaration with `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]` and then invoking the script *without* naming the target parameter explicitly (`-Path`):

```sh
"C:\Tools\scripts\BIN\SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe" -d:" " "-c:pwsh.exe -noprofile -File \"C:\Tools\scripts\VSYSCopyPathToClipboard.ps1\" $files" "%1"
```

Note the use of `-d:" "` to make `SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe` *space*-separate the (double-quoted by default) paths. Since `-File` passes the pass-through arguments *verbatim*, there is no concern about what characters the paths are composed of.

---

**Self-contained PowerShell sample code**:

The following code defines a `Copy Paths to Clipboard` shortcut-menu command for all file-system objects (except drives):

- No separate `.ps1` script is involved; instead, the code passed to `-Command` / `-c` directly performs the desired operation (copying the paths passed to the clipboard).
- The following helps with troubleshooting:

  - The full command line with which PowerShell was invoked (`[Environment]::CommandLine`) is printed, as is the list of paths passed (`$file`)
  - `-windowstyle hidden` is omitted to keep the console window in which the PowerShell commands visible and `-noexit` is added so as to keep the window open after the command has finished executing.

**Prerequisites:**

- Download and build the [`SingleInstanceAccumulator` project](https://github.com/Beej126/SingleInstanceAccumulator) using Visual Studio (using the .NET SDK is possible, but requires extra work).
- Place the resulting `SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe` file in one of the directories listed in your `$env:Path` environment variable. Alternatively, specify the full path to the executable below.

**Note:**

- `reg.exe` uses `\` as its escape character, which means that `\` characters that should become part of the string stored in the registry must be *escaped*, as `\\`.
- The sad reality as of PowerShell 7.2 is that an *extra, manual* layer of `\`-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to *external programs*. This *may* get fixed in a future version, which *may* require opt-in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details. The code below does this by way of a `-replace '"', '\"'` operation, which can easily be removed if it should no longer be necessary in a future PowerShell version.

```sh
# RUN WITH ELEVATION (AS ADMIN).

# Determine the full path of SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe:
# Note: If it isn't in $env:PATH, specify its full path instead.
$singleInstanceAccumulatorExe = (Get-Command -ErrorAction Stop SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe).Path

# The name of the shortcut-menu command to create for all file-system objects.
$menuCommandName = 'Copy Paths To Clipboard'

# Create the menu command registry key.
$null = reg.exe add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\$menuCommandName" /f /v "MultiSelectModel" /d "Player"
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw }

# Define the command line for it.
# To use *Windows PowerShell* instead, replace "pwsh.exe" with "powershell.exe"
# SEE NOTES ABOVE.
$null = reg.exe add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\$menuCommandName\command" /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d (@"
"$singleInstanceAccumulatorExe" -d:"" "-c:cmd /c echo `$files| pwsh.exe -noexit -noprofile -c \\"[Environment]::CommandLine; `$paths = `$input -split [char] 34 -ne ''; `$paths; Set-Clipboard `$paths\\"" "%1"
"@ -replace '"', '\"')

if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw }

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Shortcut menu command '$menuCommandName' successfully set up."
```

Now you can right-click on multiple files/folders in File Explorer and select `Copy Paths to Clipboard` in order to copy the full paths of all selected items to the clipboard in a single operation.

---

<sup>[1] An alternative is to use the [`-f` option](https://github.com/Beej126/SingleInstanceAccumulator#usage) instead, which causes `SingleInstanceAccumulator.exe` to write all file paths line by line to an auxiliary *text file*, and then expands `$files` to that file's full path. However, this requires the target scripts to be designed accordingly, and it is their responsibility to *clean up* the auxiliary text file.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am going to test all the code you supplied.

I appreciate that you added an example to copy paths to the clipboard. However, I have my own function for this because I perform additional numerical and alphabetical sorting that windows doesn't do by default in their built in "Copy Path" context menu item. See this: https://github.com/visusys/VSYSFileOps/blob/main/Public/Copy-PathToClipboard.ps1

Hopefully the registry syntax you provided will end this escaping nightmare. I just want to pass multiple files to my scripts without issue. Why is that so hard? :)

Comment: @Jay, I've now also updated this answer to be (hopefully) fully robust. Do note the new section about using the `-File` parameter instead, which greatly simplifies the solution - but requires you to modify your scripts accordingly.