# What registry commands allow me to run PowerShell 5 / CMD as admin from the right click context menu from a folder that has an apostrophe in it?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, registry, contextmenu

I am trying to set up my right click context menu to launch both CMD and PowerShell5 at the current directory. My PowerShell 7 commands work fine.

This is what I got:

[image: Context Menu]

The registry command to open PowerShell5 as Admin is as follows:

`PowerShell -Command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/s,/k,pushd %V && start PowerShell -NoExit && exit' -Verb RunAs"`

The registry command to open the Command Prompt as Admin is as follows:

`pwsh -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -Command "Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/s,/k,pushd,%V' -Verb RunAs"`

The registry command I have to open the Node command prompt is this:
`cmd.exe /s /k "pushd "%V" & "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat""`

(I couldn't figure out how to open the node prompt as admin).

Today, I realized that all of these commands fail if the directory I'm opening to has an apostrophe in the path or folder name. I've tried so many different registry commands and combinations of quotes and escape characters and nothing is working. It's getting enormously frustrating.

Does anyone know of any working commands to open both CMD and PowerShell 5 in directories that have an apostrophe?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys to the solution are:

- Launch via `cmd.exe` and *pipe* (`|`) the literal folder path being passed via `%V` to `powershell.exe`:

  - `cmd /c <NUL set /p="%V"` is a trick that echoes the value of `%V` *without double quotes*, even if the value contains `cmd.exe` metacharacters (it also echoes without a trailing newline, but that is not a problem here).
  - In the `powershell.exe` command line being piped to, the folder path can then be referenced *indirectly*, via the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input), which provides access to the *stdin* (piped) input.

    - This prevents problems that would arise if `%V` were embedded *directly* in the command line, notably with respect to paths containing `$` and `` ` `` characters.
  - Also, the PowerShell command can perform *string replacement* on the value of `$env:_dir` in order to double embedded `'` chars, which allows embedding the value in a verbatim `'...'` string.
- Nested `"..."` quoting for PowerShell requires intricate escaping using `\` as the escape character.
- Note: The commands invariably cause creation of a *auxiliary, transitory console window*, which the PowerShell commands hide as quickly possible and which then auto-closes. This will cause some *brief visual disruption*.

  - Avoiding this would require an additional, GUI-subsystem helper executable for launching the command lines without a visible (initial) console window. This extra level of indirection would further complicate quoting and escaping.

Note:

- The following commands are designed to be placed *verbatim* in the registry. Doing so *programmatically* complicates escaping further.
- The commands use `powershell.exe`, the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, but they should also work with `pwsh.exe`, the cross-platform, install-on-demand [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI; depending on how you installed the latter, you may have to use its *full path* in the commands below.
- You can test-drive the commands as follows:

  - Replace `%V` with the literal path of a folder of interest.
  - Submit via the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>).

---

**Commands for *elevated* sessions (run as admin):**

A `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) sesssion:

```sh
cmd /c <NUL set /p="%V" | powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -ArgumentList ('-NoExit -Command \"Push-Location -LiteralPath ''{0}''\"' -f $input.Replace(\"'\", \"''\"))"
```

A `cmd.exe` session:

```sh
cmd /c <NUL set /p="%V" | powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd -ArgumentList \"/k pushd \"\"$input\"\"\""
```

A `cmd.exe` session with the Node.js environment set up:

```sh
cmd /c <NUL set /p="%V" | powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd -ArgumentList \"/k pushd \"\"$input\"\" ^& \"\"C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat\"\"\""
```

<sup>Note: If you wanted to use environment-variable `%ProgramFiles%` instead of hard-coding `C:\Program Files` as part of the Node.js initialization-batch file path for increased robustness, you'd have to define the registry value as `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.</sup>

Running `wt.exe` (Windows Terminal), as discovered by you, with the notable need to escape `;` chars. in the path as `\;`, because `;` is a [metacharacter on the `wt.exe` command line](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/doc/specs/%23607%20-%20Commandline%20Arguments%20for%20the%20Windows%20Terminal.md#terminal_parameters)).

```sh
cmd /c <NUL set /p="%V" | powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs wt.exe -ArgumentList (\"-d \"\"{0}\" -f $input.Replace(';','\;'))"
```

<sup>Note: This approach is *shell-agnostic*. That is, Windows Terminal itself sets the working directory and then runs whatever shell is configured to be its default.</sup>

---

**Commands for *non*-elevated sessions:**

- The need for *nested* invocation of PowerShell then falls away, which simplifies the commands.
- However, for opening a *PowerShell* session special considerations apply:

  - A different approach for passing the folder path verbatim is required: an *auxiliary environment variable*, `_dir` is set, which the PowerShell commands can access as `$env:_dir`.
  - The *visual disruption* by an auxiliary, transitory console window, you have two options with the following *tradeoffs*:

    - Avoid the disruption, which has the disadvantage that *`cmd.exe`'s* console-window settings are applied (and that the initial `cmd.exe` process used to launch the PowerShell session stays alive as the PowerShell process' parent process; they terminate together, however).
    - Live with the disruption (as is inevitable *with* elevation), which has the advantage that the usual console settings associated with the PowerShell executable are used.

***No* visual disruption, but use of `cmd.exe`'s console-window settings even for PowerShell**:

A `powershell.exe` session:

```sh
cmd /c title Windows^ PowerShell & pushd "%V" & powershell.exe
```

A `cmd.exe` session (append `& "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"` for the Node.js initialization):

```sh
cmd /k pushd "%V"
```

**Visual disruption, but use of PowerShell's console-window settings**:

A `powershell.exe` session:

```sh
cmd /c pushd "%V" & start powershell.exe
```

Note:

- The above will use PowerShell's usual console-window settings, but show the *full executable path* as the window's *title*.
- While you could change the title with `start "Windows PowerShell" powershell.exe`, for instance, *default* settings then apply - you could customize them, however.
- An alternative is to change the window title from *inside* PowerShell (however, the change won't take effect until PowerShell is fully loaded):

  ```sh
  cmd /c pushd "%V" & start powershell.exe -NoExit -Command [Console]::Title='Windows PowerShell'
  ```
- Finally, if you invoke `pwsh.exe` by its *full path* and that path contains *spaces*, you need to double-quote the spaces *individually*, because double-quoting the path *as a whole* would cause it to be being mistaken for the window *title* argument (if you explicitly pass an (of necessity double-quoted) title argument, no extra work is needed); e.g.:

  ```sh
  :: Note the individually quoted space (" ")
  cmd /c pushd "%V" & start C:\PowerShell" "7\pwsh.exe
  ```