# curl: (3) Port number ended with ' ' [Powershell]

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, http-post, gitea

I am trying to make a post request in powershell using curl. But I seem to be unfortunately getting this error.

I have tried removing spaces here and there, and googling the problem but have not found a solution.

```
curl.exe -X 'POST' -H @{'Content-Type'='application/json'; 'accept'='application/json'}  -d \"{\"name\":\"test3\", \"auto_init\":true, \"default_branch\": \"master\", \"description\": \"My Test\", \"gitignores\": \"Vim\", \"issue_labels\":\"Default\", \"license\": \"DOC\", \"name\":\"test2\", \"private\":false, \"readme\":\"Default\",\"template\":false,\"trust_model\":\"default\"}\" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/repos?access_token=c11ceb97fa594a7e6c4b5519e4327908be3274b9
```

Comment: Apply [the stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7#the-stop-parsing-token) `--%`? Pass headers as a string. BTW, why do you use escaped ```\"``` at starting and ending positions in `-d` data?

Comment: @JosefZ Yah i guess i could delete those and it would still work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Re `-H`:

  - `curl.exe` is an *external program*, which means that you cannot meaningfully pass a PowerShell [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) as an argument, because it will (uselessly) be passed as literal string `System.Collections.Hashtable`.
  - Instead, pass *strings*, as *multiple* `-H` options, each in the form `'<name>: <value>'`
- Re `-d`:

  - PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) is `` ` `` (the so-called backtick), not `\`.
  - Since your argument is to be passed *verbatim* (contains no variable references to be interpolated), use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings).
  - However: The sad reality as of PowerShell 7.2 is that an *extra, manual* layer of `\`-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to *external programs*. This *may* get fixed in a future version, which *may* require opt-in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) to the linked duplicate for details.

To put it all together:

```
curl.exe -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'accept: application/json' -d '{\"name\":\"test3\", \"auto_init\":true, \"default_branch\": \"master\", \"description\": \"My Test\", \"gitignores\": \"Vim\", \"issue_labels\":\"Default\", \"license\": \"DOC\", \"name\":\"test2\", \"private\":false, \"readme\":\"Default\",\"template\":false,\"trust_model\":\"default\"}' 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/repos?access_token=c11ceb97fa594a7e6c4b5519e4327908be3274b9'
```

Note: I've omitted `-X 'POST'`, because, as [Daniel Stenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg) notes, a POST request is *implied* when you use the `-d` option.

Comment: nope i was trying to reply to you. But somehow my comment appears under his comment. It wasw YOUR code that helped me out. Thank you so much

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @ebrahim; my pleasure.