# PowerShell: escaping rules for CLI calls

Tags: powershell, escaping, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

As I have learned, when invoking PowerShell from `cmd.exe`, with the `-Command` option, escaping rules are essentially those used in Linux. So you use a backslash (`\`), rather than the usual backtick (`` ` ``).

This is to say that you don't write:

```
C:\> powershell -c "echo `"That's a single quote: ' `""
```

but

```
C:\> powershell -c "echo \"That's a single quote: ' \""
```

to get:

```
That's a single quote: '
```

And this is the exact equivalent of what you would type in a Linux terminal:

```
~ >>> bash -c "echo \"That's a single quote: ' \""
```

If I am not wrong, this  feature is named PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing.
But comparisons work up to a certain point. In fact, under Linux you write:

```
~ >>> bash -c "echo \"That's a double quote: \\\" \""
```

to get:

```
That's a double quote: "
```

while the equivalent PowerShell line:

```
C:\> powershell -c "echo \"That's a double quote: \\\"  \""
```

gives

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
```

By trial and error, I realised that:

```
C:\> powershell -c "echo \"That's a double-quote: `""  \""
```

works as expected.

Can you explain to me what is the logic behind: `` `"" ``?

Also, what are the equivalent commands when calling PowerShell from `powershell.exe`, rather than `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- On PowerShell's *command line only*, use `\"` to pass a `"` through to the code that `-c` (`-Command`) should execute.

  - Only in the resulting code does PowerShell's usual escaping of `"` as `` `" `` apply, so you may have to *combine* the two escaping techniques: `` `\" ``.

    - Your attempt, `` `"" ``, had the same effect, but it doesn't work *reliably*.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `\"` works robustly with respect to PowerShell's own parsing of its command line, but can situationally break calls *on the `cmd.exe` side* - see the bottom section for workarounds.
- When calling CLIs (external console applications) *from PowerShell*, not only do PowerShell's own, different quoting rules apply first (support for `'...'` strings, embedded `"` inside `"..."` escaped as `` `" ``), a long-standing bug up to PowerShell 7.2.x *additionally* requires escaping `"` chars. with `\` when embedded in external-program arguments (only); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

---

> this feature is named `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`

No; this feature - which became official in PowerShell 7.3 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375)) - does *not* come into play, because:

- it generally isn't (and won't be) available in the legacy *Windows PowerShell* edition that you're invoking via its CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (whereas the modern, cross-platform *PowerShell (Core)* edition's CLI is [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh))
- it only applies to calls from *inside* a PowerShell session.
- it is designed to address a long-standing problem when calling external programs with embedded `"` or empty-string string arguments *from* PowerShell - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

  - Therefore, **the linked answer addresses your *last* question**:

    - > Also, what are the equivalent commands when calling PowerShell from `powershell.exe`, rather than `cmd.exe`?
  - In short: unfortunately, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x you'll have to *additionally, manually* escape `"` chars. with `"` embedded in external-program arguments (only).

---

Why the following works from `cmd.exe`:

```bash
powershell -c "echo \"That's a single quote: ' \""
```

- **PowerShell only recognizes `\` as an escape character *on its command line*,** for consistency with other CLIs.

  - ***Inside* a PowerShell session, only `` ` `` (backtick)** serves as the escape character.
  - **Caveat**: While **`\"` to escape `"` works consistently** in both PowerShell editions **on the *PowerShell* (command-line parsing) side**, situationally it **can break `cmd.exe`'s own parsing - see the bottom section.**
- When the PowerShell CLI is invoke via `-c` (`-Command`) with a piece of PowerShell source code to execute, that code (the argument(s) following `-c` is parsed in *two stages*:

  - First, all *unescaped* `"` chars. are *stripped*, wheres *escaped ones* (`\"`) are kept and unescaped.
  - Only *then* is the result parsed and execute *as PowerShell code*.

Therefore, what PowerShell ends up executing is verbatim:

```bash
echo "That's a single quote: ' "
```

---

From the above follows why this does *not* work:

```bash
:: SYNTAX ERROR
powershell -c "echo \"That's a double quote: \\\"  \""
```

PowerShell ends up trying to execute verbatim

```bash
echo "That's a double quote: \" "
```

which is a *syntax error*, because *inside* a PowerShell session `\` doesn't escape `"` -only `` `" `` or - inside `"..."`, alternatively - `""` do.

---

From the above follows why this (mostly) works:

```bash
:: Works, but not robustly
powershell -nop -c "echo \"That's a double-quote: `""  \""
```

- `""` *sometimes*, but not always works as an alternative to `\"`;<sup>[1]</sup> here it does - see also the bottom section.
- As a result, PowerShell ends up executing the following verbatim, which works, because the escaped `"` that was passed through is now `` ` ``-escaped, as it needs to be inside a PowerShell `"..."` string:

  ```bash
   echo "That's a double-quote: `"  "
  ```

To avoid the brittle `""` escaping, it is better to formulate this command by combining the required `` ` ``-escaping with the command-line `\`-escaping - i.e. `` `\" `` - but see the bottom section for a fully robust solution:

```bash
powershell -nop -c "echo \"That's a double-quote: `\"  \""
```

---

**Avoiding parsing problems *on the `cmd.exe` side*, a safe alternative to `\"`:**

While **`\"` to escape `"` works consistently** in both PowerShell editions **on the *PowerShell*  (command-line parsing) side**, situationally it **can break `cmd.exe`'s own parsing**. By contrast, using `\"` is safe when calling from *no-shell* environments such as Task Scheduler.

While there are **workarounds**, they are, unfortunately PowerShell **edition-specific**:

- In *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`)

  - Use `"^""` (sic) instead of `\"`
- In *PowerShell (Core)* (v6+, `pwsh.exe`)

  - Use `""` instead of `\"`

Important:

- These **workarounds require** that the ***whole code*** to pass to `-c` (`-Command`) **be passed as a *single*, `"..."`-enclosed argument**.
- `-c` (`-Command`) also accepts *multiple* arguments - which may *individually* be double-quoted or not - in which case it simply concatenates these arguments, after having stripped unescaped `"`, to form the code to execute. This technique situationally allows you to get away with `\"`-escaping (e.g., `` powershell -c \"Between 2 & 3`\"\" ``, but (a) it requires you to pay close attention to which parts of the command `cmd.exe` will see as *unquoted*, (b) would require you to `^`-escape any `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` in those parts, and (c) invariably performs *whitespace normalization*, i.e. folds runs of *multiple* spaces into a single one each.

The following calls, designed to print verbatim  `Between 2 & 3"` , demonstrate this:

```bash
:: BREAKS, because cmd.exe sees `&` as *outside a double-quoted string*
powershell -c " \" Between 2 & 3`\" \" "

:: PowerShell (Core) workaround
pwsh -c " "" Between 2 & 3`"" "" "

:: Windows PowerShell workaround
powershell -c " "^"" Between 2 & 3`"^"" "^"" "
```

---

<sup>[1] An example of where `""` inside `"..."` *doesn't* work is `` powershell -c "echo \" Nat `""King`"" Cole  \"" ``: instead of `Nat "King" Cole`, it prints `Nat "King Cole`, i.e. the second escaped `"` is missing (it would work fine in `pwsh.exe`, however, as discussed in the bottom section). It's ultimately not worth speculating how, precisely, embedded `""` sequences are parsed by `powershell.exe -c`, given that it demonstrably isn't reliable and that reliable alternatives do exist (`\"` or, from `cmd.exe`, also `"^""`).</sup>

Comment: I am replacing `!` for the backtick. If external quotes are stripped and internal kept unescaped (like in Bash), what is passed to PowerShell in `powershell -c "echo \"That's a double-quote: !""  \""`  should be `echo "That's a double-quote: !"" "`, but this would not work as PS code.

Comment: @antonio, `""` is _situationally_ retained as `"` by `powershell.exe`, as explained in the answer, but, because it doesn't work _robustly_, it should be avoided (except in `pwsh.exe`, where it is safe to use). What `powershell.exe` sees in your example is ``echo "That's a double quote: `" "``

Comment: @antonio, if you want an example of where `""`-escaping falls apart, try ``powershell -c "echo \" Nat `""King`"" Cole  \""`` - you'll see that the second escaped `"` is missing; by contrast, with `pwsh.exe` it works fine and prints the desired `Nat "King" Cole`

Comment: @antonio It's ultimately not worth speculating how, precisely, embedded `""` sequences are parsed by `powershell.exe -c`, given that it demonstrably isn't reliable and that reliable alternatives do exist (`\"` or, from `cmd.exe`, also `"^""`)