# PowerShell 7.3.0 breaking command invocation

Tags: powershell, escaping, winscp, quoting, powershell-7.3

I use WinSCP within a Powershell script. It suddenly stopped working. After a while I could figure out that the problem appeared from a more recent version of PowerShell:

Reduced code:

```
& winscp `
    /log `
    /command `
        'echo Connecting...' `
        "open sftp://kjhgk:jkgh@example.com/ -hostkey=`"`"ssh-ed25519 includes spaces`"`""
```

Error message using v7.2.7

> Host "example.com" does not exist.

Errror message using v7.3.0

> Too many parameters for command 'open'.

As you can see with v7.3.0 WinSCP receives different input depending on the version of PS. I found out that the difference has something to do with the spaces in the hostkey. If they are omitted v7.3.0 outputs the same error.

What change to PowerShell caused this, and how can I fix it?
(How can I debug such issues? I played a bit around with escaping, but the strings look the same no matter the version, no obvious breaking change that could be responsible)

Comment: Re troubleshooting external-program argument-passing: If you use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), you can use `choco install echoargs -y` from an elevated session to install `echoargs.exe`, which shows the raw command line that PowerShell builds behind the scenes, and how (most) external programs parse it into arguments. Alternatively, you can compile a utility ad hoc: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832150/45375). In PowerShell 7.3+, you'll only see the broken legacy behavior if you explicitly (temporarily) set `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'` first.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Version 7.3.0 of [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) introduced a *breaking change* with respect to how *arguments with embedded `"` characters* (and *empty-string* arguments)<sup>[1]</sup> are passed to *external programs***, such as `winscp`:<sup>[2]</sup>

While this change is *mostly* beneficial, because **it fixes behavior that was fundamentally broken since v1** ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) discusses the old, broken behavior), it ***also* invariably *breaks existing workarounds*** that build on the broken behavior, *except* those for calls to *batch files* and the WSH CLIs (`wscript.exe` and `cscript.exe`) and their associated script files (with file-name extensions such as `.vbs` and `.js`).

**To make existing workarounds continue to work, set the [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing) (temporarily) to `'Legacy'`**:

```bash
# Note: Enclosing the call in & { ... } makes it execute in a *child scope*
#       limiting the change to $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing to that scope.
& {
  $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'
  & winscp `
    /log `
    /command `
        'echo Connecting...' `
        "open sftp://kjhgk:jkgh@example.com/ -hostkey=`"`"ssh-ed25519 includes spaces`"`"" 
}
```

Unfortunately, because `winscp.exe` only accepts
`"open sftp://kjhgk:jkgh@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 includes spaces"""` on its process command line (i.e., embedded `"` escaped as `""`), and not also the most widely used form
`"open sftp://kjhgk:jkgh@example.com/ -hostkey=\"ssh-ed25519 includes spaces\""` (embedded `"` escaped as `\"`), which the fixed behavior now employs, **for `winscp.exe`, specifically, a workaround will continue to be required**.

**If you *don't* want to rely on having to modify `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`** for the workaround, here are **workarounds that function in *both* v7.2- and v7.3+** :

- Use **`--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token)**, which, however, comes with pitfalls and severe limitations, notably the inability to (directly) use PowerShell *variables* or subexpressions in the arguments that follow it - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375) for details; however, you can bypass these limitations if you use `--%` as part of an *array* that you construct and assign to a variable first and then pass via [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting):

  ```bash
  # Note: Must be single-line; note the --% and the 
  #       unescaped use of "" in the argument that follows it.
  #       Only "..." quoting must be used after --% 
  #       and the only variables that can be used are cmd-style 
  #       *environment variables* such as %OS%.
  winscp /log /command 'echo Connecting...' --% "open sftp://kjhgk:jkgh@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 includes spaces""" 

  # Superior alternative, using splatting:
  $argList = '/log', '/command', 'echo Connecting...', 
             '--%', "open sftp://kjhgk:jkgh@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 includes spaces"""
  winscp @argList
  ```
- Alternatively, **call via `cmd /c`**:

  ```bash
  # Note: Pass-through command must be single-line,
  #       Only "..." quoting supported, 
  #       and the embedded command must obey cmd.exe's syntax rules.
  cmd /c @"
    winscp /log /command "echo Connecting..." "open sftp://kjhgk:jkgh@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 includes spaces"""
  "@
  ```

  - Note: You don't strictly need to use a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@` or `@'<newline>...<newline>'@`), but it helps readability and simplifies using embedded quoting.

Both workarounds allow you to pass arguments *directly as quoted*, but unfortunately also require formulating the entire (pass-through) command *on a single line* - except if `--%` is combined with splatting.

---

##### Background information:

The v7.3+ default `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` value on Windows, `'Windows'`:

- regrettably ***retains* the old, broken behavior** for calls to ***batch files* and the WSH CLIs (`wscript.exe` and `cscript.exe`) and their associated script files (with file-name extensions such as `.vbs` and `.js`)**.

  - While, for these programs only, this allows existing workarounds to continue to function, *future* code that only needs to run in v7.3+ will continue to be burdened by the need for these obscure workarounds, which *build on broken behavior*.

    - The alternative, which was *not* implemented, would have been to build accommodations for these programs as well as some program-agnostic accommodations *into PowerShell*, so that in the vast majority of case there won't even be a need for workarounds in the future: see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143).
  - There are also [troublesome signs that this list of exceptions will be appended to, piecemeal](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/18559), which all but guarantees confusion for a given PowerShell version as to which programs require workarounds and which don't.
- commendably, **for all other programs** PowerShell encodes the arguments - when it of necessity *rebuilds* the command line behind the scenes - as follows with respect to `"`:

  - It **encodes the arguments for programs that follow the [C++ command-line parsing rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args#parsing-c-command-line-arguments) (as used by C / C++ / .NET applications) / the parsing rules of the  [`CommandLineToArgv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) WinAPI function**, which are the *most widely observed convention* for parsing a process' command line.
  - In a nutshell, this means that ***embedded* `"` characters** *embedded* in an argument, to be seen as a *verbatim part* of it by the target program, are **escaped as `\"`**, with `\` itself requiring escaping *only* (as `\\`) if it precedes a `"` but is meant to be interpreted *verbatim*.
  - Note that if you set `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` value to `'Standard'` (which is the default on Unix-like platforms, where this mode fixes *all* problems and makes v7.3+ code never require workarounds), this behavior applies to *all* external programs, i.e. the above exceptions no longer apply).

For a **summary of the impact of the breaking v7.3 change**, see [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13428#issuecomment-1297723605).

If you **have / need to write cross-edition, cross-version PowerShell code**: The [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) (`Install-Module Native`; authored by me), has an **`ie`** function (short for: Invoke Executable), which is a polyfill that provides workaround-free cross-edition (v3+), cross-platform, and cross-version behavior in the *vast majority* of cases - simply prepend `ie`  to your external-program calls.
**Caveat**: In the specific case at hand it will *not* work, because it isn't aware that `winscp.exe` requires `""`-escaping.

---

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76917546/45375) for details and workarounds.</sup>

<sup>[2] *Reverting* that change in a later version and making the new behavior *opt-in* was briefly considered, but decided against - see [GitHub issue #18694](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18694#issuecomment-1489378453)</sup>