# How to add quotation marks on a value on registry?

Tags: powershell, escaping, registry, quotes

How do I add into the registry in which the value of the UninstallString needs to have quotation marks at the beginning and end.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)
```

[image]

tried to edit the value of the registry with this but received an error

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)" -Name "UninstallString" -Value ""C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)\install.exe"" -PropertyType "String"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to this: **how can I pass an argument that has *embedded* `"` characters, i.e. `"` characters that are a *verbatim* part of the argument?**

Specifically, you want `New-ItemProperty`'s `-Value` parameter to see the following value *verbatim*:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)\install.exe"
```

The **tl;dr** solution, using `'...'` quoting, is:

```
New-ItemProperty `
  -Path "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)" -Name "UninstallString" `
  -Value '"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)\install.exe"' `
  -PropertyType String
```

Your own attempt - passing `""C:\Program Files\...""` - was flawed in that the initial `""` created an *empty-string* argument, followed by argument `C:\Program`, and so on - which isn't what you intendded.

Read on for a  overview of all solution options.

---

The following is a **systematic overview** of the **solution options**; it uses [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) and verbatim value `"foo bar"` for brevity, which enables easy verification of whether the argument was passed as intended:

- Use a [**verbatim** (single-quoted) string (**`'...'`**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), if the **value can be expressed *as such*, i.e., *literally***:

```
Write-Output '"foo bar"'
```

- Use an [**expandable** (double-quoted) string (**`"..."`**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), if the **value must be derived from *variable values* and/or *subexpressions***:

  - Inside `"..."`, embedded `"` chars. must be *escaped*; while *doubling* them works (`""`), the preferable solution for consistency is to use **`` `" ``**, because it uses PowerShell's general-purpose [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters), `` ` ``, the so-called backtick:

```
$var = 'foo'
Write-Output "`"$var bar`""
```

---

**Alternatively**, use the **[here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) *variants*** of the string-literal forms shown above, whose **syntax is invariably *multiline***, and which are especially useful for defining *multiline strings* in a readable format; however, they are also useful for defining single-line strings, because they **avoid the need for escaping of embedded quotes**:

- ***Verbatim* (single-quoted) here-string**:

  - Note: Since `"` do not require escaping in *regular* `'...'` strings anyway, there's not much benefit to using the here-string form in this case.
  - However, if the string contained embedded `'` chars., you would benefit from not having to escape them (in *regular* verbatim strings, you'd have to escape them as `''`).

```
Write-Output @'
"foo bar"
'@ # IMPORTANT: Closing delimiter must be at the VERY START OF THE LINE
```

- ***Expandable* (double-quoted) here-string**:

  - Note how the embedded `"` need *no* escaping in this case.
  - The only character that *potentially* needs escaping - with `` ` `` - is `$`, namely if you do *not* want it to be considered the start of variable reference (e.g,. `$foo`) or subexpression (e.g, `$(1 + 2)`) to be expanded.

```
$var = 'foo'
Write-Output @"
"$var bar"
"@ # IMPORTANT: Closing delimiter must be at the VERY START OF THE LINE
```

---

**Caveat** re calling **external programs**:

- **Up to PowerShell 7.2.x**, the sad reality is that **an *extra, manual* layer of `\`-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required**.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).
- **Since PowerShell 7.3.0**, this is **now *mostly* no longer necessary**, but on Windows there are selective exceptions:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).