# Powershell Core, MXLinuxv21, running linux /usr/bin/x command results in "no file found" for objects command operates on

Tags: linux, powershell

I have a powershell script with three sections: 1. modify file names to remove MicrosoftOS reserved characters; 2. run /usr/bin/flac to convert *.wav files to *.flac, 3. use .dll to copy ID3 tags from *.mp3 files to *.flac files.

All three sections of this script *worked* on my previous Kubuntu v22.10 system. This script fails at step 2 on MXLinux v21. The error is "File not found" for the *objects* of the /usr/bin/flac command. /usr/bin/flac loads, but says that it cannot find the file given to it. Steps 1 and 3 work (I know this because the script takes an argument to skip step 2; thus I can run it if the *.wav files are already *.flac files, e.g., on a previous run where step 2 was successful but step 3 failed for some reason).

Here is the PS code fragment:

```
  [string] $flacEXE = '/usr/bin/flac'
  if($convert -eq "yes" || $convert -eq "Yes" || $convert -eq "YES") 
  {
    if (Test-Path -Path "$workingPath/*cr.wav")
    { 
      $CRFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$workingPath/*cr.wav"
      foreach ($crFile in $CRFiles)
      {
        $output = & $flacEXE "`"$crFile`""
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) 
        {
          Write-Host "The flac conversion created an error..." -ForegroundColor Red
          Write-Host "$output" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      Write-Host "No ClickRepair files found but Convert was Yes ... Aborting script.`n" -ForegroundColor Red
      throw $_.Exception.Message
      exit      
    }
  }
```

If I run /usr/bin/flac from the prompt in powershell (e.g., in Visual Studio Code), it fails. If I run /usr/bin/flac from a linux terminal on the same files in the same folder, it works.

I think this must be some sort of permissions issue (scope issue?), but cannot figure it out. The files are on a NTFS USB volume mounted on /mnt/. I recently migrated to MXLinux and thus have recreated my system. This is my first use of this powershell script.

I should note that the concert of Set-ExecutionPolicy is not valid for Powershell Core on Linux, only on Windows systems, so that's not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

> `` $output = & $flacEXE "`"$crFile`"" ``

with:

```
$output = & $flacEXE $crFile
```

- Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, **you do *not* need to enclose variable references passed as arguments in `"..."` in PowerShell** - PowerShell has no equivalent to the so-called shell expansions of POSIX-compatible shells, notably not word-splitting; therefore, a value with spaces doesn't need protecting with `"..."` in PowerShell.
- **That `` "`"$crFile`"" `` worked at all is only due to a longstanding bug** in how PowerShell passes arguments with *embedded* double quotes to *external programs* up to PowerShell 7.2.x.

  - In PowerShell 7.3.0, this bug was fixed, so that the above now (correctly) passes the inner `"` *as a a verbatim part of the argument* to the target program. (However, `"$crFile"`, would work in both 7.2.x and later, though the `"` are still unnecessary, as explained above).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for more information, including how to opt into the old, broken behavior for the sake of backward compatibility. Also note that the current plan is to continue to *default* to the new, correct behavior on Unix-like platforms only, and that *on Windows* some version *after* 7.3.1 may revert to the old, broken behavior *by default*, with the new, correct behavior requiring *opt-in*.

---

As an aside, re `if($convert -eq "yes" || $convert -eq "Yes" || $convert -eq "YES")`:

- Replace `if($convert -eq "yes" || $convert -eq "Yes" || $convert -eq "YES")` with **`if ($convert -eq 'yes')`** - **PowerShell is case-*insensitive* by default**.<sup>[1]</sup> If you had to use ***multiple* operations, you need to chain them with `-or`, not with `||`** - `||` operates on the *success status of commands*, not on *values*; e.g.:

  - `$true || 'never get here'` and `$false || 'never get here'` do *not* trigger the RHS of `||`, because both `$true` and `$false` are expression that *execute successfully*, *irrespective of their value*, and therefore do *not* trigger the RHS of the [`||` pipeline-chain operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators) (applies analogously to `&&`).
  - For operations based on *values* (expression *return values* or command *output*), us the `-or`, the [logical `-or` and `-and` operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators).

---

<sup>[1] For case-*sensitive* behavior, use the `c`-prefixed variants of operands such as `-eq`; e.g., `'FOO' -ceq 'foo'` is `$false`. Similarly, most standard cmdlets and the `switch` statement are case-insensitive by default, and offer a `-CaseSensitive` switch as *opt-in*.</sup>

Comment: mklement0 - spot on. Changing "`"$crFile`"" to $crFile results in the expected behavior - command now "sees" and processes the files. And you are, of course, correct that || should be -OR. Mixing up what shell/environment I'm working in.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @GuyStalnaker. Quoting is a mess in PowerShell with respect to calling external programs, but passing values that don't have embedded `"` is straightforward (easier than in Bash, for instance). Fortunately, in 7.3+ _on Unix_, even embedded `"`, when truly needed, are now handled correctly by default.