# Python argparse not working corrrectly with path in Windows

Tags: python, powershell, argparse

The `argparse` library in python doesn't work for any path containing a space and `\` (backslash) at the end.  The parser will parse the backslash at the end of path to be `"` (double quotation).

The code below is a sample that has same problem:

```
import argparse


if __name__=="__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--weight', type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args.weight_path)
```

For example in PowerShell:

```
PS > python sample.py -w ".\test test\"
.\test test"
```

It does work for any path which doesn't contain a space:

```
PS > python sample.py -w ".\testtest\"
.\test test\
PS > python sample.py -w "testtest\"
test test\
PS > python sample.py -w "testtest"
test test
```

Is there any issues with using `argparse` with PowerShell?

I don't even know how to search for a solution to this problem...

Comment: `argparse` does not change any input strings.  It uses the strings in `sys.argv` exactly as given.  But its entirely possible that powershell has edited those commandline values.

Comment: You should install the updated cross-platform PowerShell 7.x, which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing what is a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell***, which has since been **corrected in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**:

- To PowerShell, based on the syntax of its own [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules), the verbatim value of string `".\test test\"` is `.\test test\`, because `\` has *no* special meaning in PowerShell (PowerShell's escape character is `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*).
- However, based on the [most widely used conventions for parsing a *process* command line on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args#parsing-c-command-line-arguments), this string must be placed as `".\test test\\"` on the process command line constructed *behind the scenes* when calling an *external program*, given that processes are expected to parse `\"`  as an *escaped* `"` char.

  - While *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now *does* do that behind the scenes, *Windows PowerShell* does *not*: it places `".\test test\"`, which causes Python to interpret the closing `\"` as a *verbatim* `"` (while *not* complaining that a closing *unescaped* `"` - i.e. one with *syntactic* function - is then *missing*).

The ***workaround* for Windows PowerShell is to *manually* double the `\` char. before the closing `"`**:

```bash
# Windows PowerShell only: double the \ before the closing "
python sample.py -w ".\test test\\"
```

---

As an aside: While *PowerShell (Core) 7+* has fixed *this particular problem*, there is still a long-standing problem with respect to *intentionally* embedded `"` characters in arguments passed to external programs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

Comment: Wild. I bet this has caused a lot of people untold pain.

Comment: Can you explain why this doesn't seem to be an issue for the powershell `echo` command? Is this somehow different than a normal process?

Comment: @flakes, the problem only surfaces with calls to _external programs_ - calls to PowerShell-native commands aren't affected (such as to `echo`, a built-in alias of [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)). Unfortunately, the problem at hand is just the tip of the iceberg - please see the link I've added to the answer.

Comment: It actually works with PowerShell 7. It's enough for me. Thank you :).