# I need to pass a powershell variable to a to a FontForge "Script String" (-c) but can't. Need help invoking FontForge with a dynamic variable

Tags: powershell, command-line, fonts, fontforge, ttx-fonttools

Here is my code:

```
$CurrentFile = $_
$DestPath = "FontForge Export"

if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $DestPath -PathType Container)){
    New-Item -Path $DestPath -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}

fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export("FontForge Export/%n-%e.svg");' $CurrentFile
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the `fontforge` call to accept a powershell variable in the `Export("FontForge Export/%n-%e.svg");` block. The above code works because I've defined a hard-coded directory name ("FontForge Export"). But as soon as I try something like this:

```
$CurrentFile = $_
$FullNoExt = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($CurrentFile)
$DestFolder =  "$FullNoExt FontForge Export"

if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $DestFolder -PathType Container)){
    New-Item -Path $DestFolder -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}

fontforge -lang=ff -c "Open(`$1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export("$DestFolder/%n-%e.svg");" $CurrentFile
```

I get en error:

```
Couldn't find a font file named C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/Test/Adobe CC Acumin Pro/Acumin Pro Black FontForge Export/%n-%e.svg);
The requested file, %n-%e.svg);, does not exist
Open: Failed to open: Acumin Pro Black FontForge Export/%n-%e.svg);
Called from...
 <command-string>: line 1
```

I need a dynamic output folder from FontForge so I can run the script in parallel over several typefaces.

No matter what I do I just can't finesse the correct syntax.

Can someone help?

I really need some fresh eyes.

**Adding some more information:**

Tried using the format operator with no success either.

```
$cmdd = "$DestFolder/%n-%e.svg"
fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export({0});' $CurrentFile -f $cmdd
```

Comment: Are you running in windows?   Then why are you separating folder names in the path with forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: @jdweng I've tried both forward and backslashes, output is the same. `The requested file, %n-%e.svg);, does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

**Fundamentally**:

- PowerShell, up to v7.2.x (including *Windows PowerShell*) is broken with respect to passing arguments with *embedded* `"` characters to *external programs*, necessitating *manual `\`-escaping*
- This has been fixed in v7.3+, but with *selective exceptions on Windows*.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for details.

---

> `` "Open(`$1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export("$DestFolder/%n-%e.svg");" ``

What your attempt lacks is escaping of the *embedded* `"` characters in the argument that is overall enclosed in `"..."`; inside `"..."`, PowerShell requires *embedded* `"` chars. to be escaped as `` `" `` (or `""`):

```
# Sufficient in v7.3+
"Open(`$1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export(`"$DestFolder/%n-%e.svg`");"

# In v7.2-, additional \-escaping is needed:
"Open(`$1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export(\`"$DestFolder/%n-%e.svg\`");"
```

---

While an `-f`-based approach would work too, it requires the *entire `-f` operation to be enclosed in `(...)`*:

```
# Sufficient in v7.3+
('Open($1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export("{0}/%n-%e.svg");' -f $DestFolder)

# In v7.2-, additional \-escaping is needed:
('Open($1); SelectAll(); UnlinkReference(); Export(\"{0}/%n-%e.svg\");' -f $DestFolder)
```