# sed giving error when repetition is used in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, sed, escaping

I was writing a powershell script and I need to use sed to extract some part of the output of a different command. It looks something like this:

```
echo "d6121090" | sed -E "s/^d6(.*)10.*/\\1/"
12
```

But if I replace `.*` in sed with `.{0,}` or with `{0,2}` sed is giving me error:

```
echo "d6121090" | sed -E "s/^d6(.{0,})10.*/\\1/"
/usr/bin/sed: can't read s/^d6(.)10.*/\1/: No such file or directory
```

```
echo "d6121090" | sed -E "s/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\\1/"
/usr/bin/sed: can't read s/^d6(.2)10.*/\1/: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if the error has something to do with sed or powershell.

I'm using sed provided by `Cygwin (4.9-1)`, version is `(GNU sed) 4.9`.

If there is a better way to extract a part of string then please mention that also.

Comment: Don't know about powershell, but perhaps `^d6(.?.?)10` could help. Also, you don't need the `.*` after `10`.

Comment: @Sundeep this is just an minimal reproducible example. The actual repetition I'm using contains many repetitions and it is hard and error prone to write that many dots.

Comment: oh ok, try escaping the `{` and `}` characters...

Comment: try lowercase '-e' instead of uppercase '-E'.

Comment: fwiw, all three examples give ```12``` in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on WIndows 11 WSL, with ```sed --version``` showing ```sed (GNU sed) 4.8 Packaged by Debian```

Comment: @Sundeep It worked.. by escaping `\`. I had previously tried escaping by doubling up, which didn't work.

Comment: @mclayton issue with powershell I think. It messes with braces.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Is the example in your question the exact pattern you're using with `sed`? If not, please post the actual expression you're using...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, I'm using the exact pattern and it is giving the said error.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB, no, `{` and `}` aren't special inside `"..."` or `'...'` in PowerShell. The problem comes from PowerShell passing arguments that don't contain spaces _unquoted_ to external programs, and it is the use of `{` and `}` in an unquoted argument on the Cygwin side that causes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**Workarounds**, in descending order of preference (note that `echo "d6121090"` was simplified to just `'d6121090'`, using PowerShell's *implicit output behavior* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375)):

- Use **`'...'` quoting *embedded inside `"..."`***:

  ```bash
  'd6121090' | sed -E "'s/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\1/'"
  ```

  - Note: This takes advantage of the fact that - unusually - the Cygwin-provided executables also recognize `'...'` quoting on their command lines.

    - Using `'"..."'` instead (quotes swapped) - surprisingly - works as-is up to PowerShell v7.2.x; it should never have worked, but did due to a long-standing bug with respect to passing arguments with embedded `"` chars. to external programs. This was (mostly) fixed in v7.3, where you can opt-into the old, broken behavior with `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for details.
- Use an extra space to force PowerShell to *quote* the `sed` script on the process command line built behind the scenes (see next section).

  ```bash
  'd6121090' | sed -E 's/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\1/ ' # <- Note the trailing space
  ```
- Call via `cmd.exe`, which allows you to control quoting *explicitly* (the spaces around `"` are just for readability).

  ```bash
  'd6121090' | cmd /c " sed -E 's/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\1/' "
  ```
- Use `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token) to pass the remainder of the command line *as-is*, but note its *fundamental limitations*, discussed in the bottom section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

  ```bash
  'd6121090' | sed -E --% 's/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\1/'
  ```

---

##### Background information:

You're seeing the **confluence of two surprising behaviors**:

- When you invoke a **Cygwin** utility such as `sed` *from a Windows shell* such as PowerShell, the command line is interpreted *as if it had been submitted from a POSIX-compatible shell* such as Bash.

  - On the plus side, this allows you to use `'...'` quoting even when calling from `cmd.exe`, even though CLIs on Windows normally only understand `"..."` quoting.
- **PowerShell** - of necessity (on Windows) - *rebuilds* the command line it uses to launch child processes behind the scenes, because its own command-line syntax - notably the ability to use `'...'` strings - cannot be expected to be understood by outside CLIs (which on Windows are expected to recognize `"..."` strings only).

  - However, PowerShell employs *on-demand* double-quoting when it rebuilds the command line, based solely on whether an argument *contains spaces*.  Therefore, what was verbatim `"s/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\\1/"` on the original command line is placed as verbatim `s/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\\1/` - without quoting! - on the process command line.
  - This is normally *not* a problem, given that most CLIs use their arguments *verbatim* rather than subjecting them to shell-like interpretation.

    - It is, however, also a problem with `cmd.exe`, both in direct `cmd /c` calls as well indirectly, when calling *batch files*; [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143), among other suggested improvements, proposed modifying PowerShell to accommodate this quirk and double-quote even space-less arguments if they contain `cmd.exe` metacharacters, but it looks like such improvements won't be implemented.

Therefore, the command line that PowerShell actually submits is the following - note the absence of quoting:

```bash
sed -E s/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\\1/
```

The lack of quoting around the `sed` script causes Cygwin to treat `{` and `}` as Bash [*brace expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) expression, which therefore expands to *multiple* arguments, with the extra argument getting interpreted as a - non-existent - *filename*.

You can verify this as follows, using Cygwin's `printf.exe`:

```bash
# From PowerShell
printf '%s\n' 's/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
s/^d6(.0)10.*/1/
s/^d6(.2)10.*/1/
```

That is, the brace expansion turned `.{0, 2}` into *two* arguments, `.0` and `.2`, along with the prefix and suffix string, and the second argument was then interpreted as a filename.

---

There are several **workarounds**, as shown above, but the simplest one in this case is to *append a space* to your `sed` script, which doesn't interfere with the script's function, but forces PowerShell to enclose the script in `"..."` behind the scenes (in cases where adding an extra space would interfere with the intended functionality, such as when passing a space-less search pattern to `grep`, use the `"'...'"` technique shown at the top):

```bash
'd6121090' | sed -E 's/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\1/ ' # <- Note the trailing space
```

Note:

- `'...'` quoting is used on the PowerShell side, which is generally preferable when you're dealing with *verbatim* (literal) values.
- The `\` before `\1` is *not* escaped; to PowerShell itself, `\` is never special.

  - See the bottom section for more information about PowerShell string literals.
- Even though the `'...'` quoting gets translated to `"..."` quoting behind the scenes, `\` also does *not* require escaping on the Cygwin side (though doing so would *also* work). This, along with the fact that an *unquoted* argument such as `s/^d6(.{0,2})10.*/\1/` would cause a *syntax error* on the Bash command line - due to the unescaped `(` and `)` - suggests that Cygwin employs some kind of *hybrid* approach to parsing the command line (presumably built into each and every `.exe` that Cygwin comes with).

---

> if there is a better way to extract a part of string then please mention that also.

PowerShell has great [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) support built in, and its [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator allows you to do what `sed`'s `s///` function does, only *more efficiently*, because the operation is performed *in-process*:

```bash
# From PowerShell
'd6121090' -replace '^d6(.{0,2})10.*', '$1' # -> '12'
```

---

**PowerShell's string literals and escaping**:

- In PowerShell's [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), **`\` has *no* special meaning** (and neither do `{` and `}`).

  - **PowerShell's escape characters is `` ` ``**, the so-called backtick, and inside `"..."` only *it* and `$` have special meaning (the latter for referencing variables and subexpressions to be expanded (interpolated)) and therefore need escaping with `` ` `` if meant to be used *verbatim*.
  - Similar to POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash, PowerShell also has [verbatim (single-quoted) strings (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) **`'...'` is generally preferable when expressing regexes or substitution expressions**.

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew powershell would do such preprocessing before handing over.. Thanks.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB, unfortunately, this preprocessing is unavoidable on Windows (on _Unix_, the problem normally doesn't arise, as there is no concept of a _process_-level command line). While in _this_ case PowerShell is arguably not to blame, it _is_ to blame with respect to its broken handling of arguments with embedded `"` chars. up to v7.2.x; this was _mostly_ fixed in v7.3, with selective (and unfortunate) exceptions on Windows - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

Comment: The solution with trailing space works for sed. But it doesn't work for grep I guess.. You have any sugetions?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB, I've added a new workaround to the top section; in short: use `"'...'"`