# pass parameters from PowerShell to a jar file

Tags: java, powershell

When I pass parameters to a JAR, the Java application generates a  PDF file which contains the values of the parameters passed, but  the  problem is when one these parameters is empty, one parameter takes the value of another one.

Example:

```
d:
cd D:\JavaApp\ITEquipmentPassV2
$Name=@"
$[Name]
"@
$Region=@"
$[Region]
"@
$Device=@"
$[Device]
"@
$ForHO=@"
$[ForHO]
"@
$Ex_Pas=@"
$[Ex_Pa]
"@
$Ex_Pass_Nr=@"
$[Ex_Pass_Nr]
"@
$Monitor=@"
$[Monitorl]
"@
java -jar JavaApp_v2.jar $Name $Region $Device $ForHO $Ex_Pas $Ex_Pass_Nr $Monitor
```

If `$Ex_Pas` is empty or contains a special character then `$forHo` takes the value of `$Monitor`.

Comment: What's with the `$[...]` syntax? Are you running your script through some sort of template engine to generate the correct arguments?

Comment: Shouldn't you be quoting those parameters?

Comment: You need double quote the params. e.g. java -jar JavaApp_v2.jar "$Name" "$Region" "$Device" "$ForHO" "$Ex_Pas" "$Ex_Pass_Nr" "$Monitor"

Comment: @Tristate: In PowerShell - unlike in `cmd.exe` and  in POSIX-compatible shells 
 such as Bash - variable references used as command arguments do NOT need double-quoting (even if they contain spaces or other shell metacharacters).

Comment: @ajra: A variable containing the _empty string_ indeed causes a problem _on the PowerShell side_, as described below. _Special characters_ are _not_ a problem on the PowerShell side, though can be for target programs with nonstandard argument parsing, such as batch files.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- The symptom is likely caused by variables containing the *empty string* (see below), even though the sample argument values in the question never result in such, given that *no* string interpolation is performed, because the syntax form `$[var]` isn't a valid variable reference.
- You also mention *special characters* as a problem, though that is unlikely, given that PowerShell passes them through correctly, even with variable references *not* enclosed in `"..."`, the latter generally not being necessary in PowerShell (e.g., `some.exe $var` is sufficient, no need for `some.exe "$var"`).

---

> but the problem is when **if one these parameter is empty, one parameter takes the value of another one**

You're likely seeing a **long-standing bug** present in ***Windows PowerShell*** and in **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to version 7.2.x*** - it has been **fixed in v7.3+**, with **selective exceptions on Windows** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for details (it focuses on arguments with *embedded double-quotes*, but the issue at hand is part of the problem).

- **Trying to pass an *empty string* (`""`, `''`) as an argument to an *external program* is *quietly ignored***; that is, no argument is passed at all.
- Note that, by contrast, passing `$null` is ignored *by design*.

**Examples**:

The following uses `python` to simply echo the arguments it was passed.

```bash
# Pass an empty-string *literal*
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' '' hi

# Pass an empty string via a *variable*
$someArg=''
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' $someArg hi
```

- The expected output is `['', 'hi']`
- With the bug present, the output is `['hi']`, indicating that the empty string wasn't passed at all.

**Workarounds**:

- Passing an empty string *literally*:

  - Use **`'""'`** (sic) (`` `"`" `` works too):

    ```bash
    # In WinPS and PS Core v7.2.x- only
    # (In v7.3+, use it only with $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'.)
    python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' '""' hi
    ```
  - Alternatively, on Windows only, use `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token) in combination with `""` (*not* `''`), but note its **many limitations**, detailed in the bottom section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375), notably the inability to embed PowerShell variables and expressions:

    ```bash
    # Windows only.
    python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' --% "" hi
    ```
- Passing an empty string *via variables* that may or may not contain the empty string:

  - With an *individual* argument:

    ```bash
    $someArg = ''
    python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' ($someArg, '""')[$someArg -is [string] -and -not $someArg] hi
    ```
  - With an *array* of arguments:

    ```bash
    $someArgs = '', 'hi'
    python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' $someArgs.ForEach({
        ($_, '""')[$_ -is [string] -and -not $_]
      })
    ```
  - Explanation of the `($someArg, '""')[$someArg -is [string] -and -not $someArg]` technique:

    - It is the concise equivalent of:

      ```bash
      if ($someArg -is [string] -and -not $someArg) { '""' } else { $someArg }
      ```
    - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can also use the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false)

      ```bash
       ($someArg -is [string] -and -not $someArg ? '""' : $someArg)
      ```
    - It emulates a conditional using an *array* to represent the return values, and relies on a *Boolean* value getting implicitly converted to an *integer* in the context of an index expression (`[...]`), with `$false` becoming `0`, and `$true` becoming `1`, so that the appropriate array element is returned.<sup>[1]</sup>
    - If you know `$someArg` to *always be a string*, you can simplify to one of the following:

      ```bash
      ($someArg, '""')[-not $someArg]
      # PS v7+ only
      (-not $someArg ? '""' : $someArg)
      ```
    - All variants rely on PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversions, which treat an *empty string* as `$false`, and any nonempty one as `$true`. The complete rules are summarized in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).

---

**Module-based polyfill**:

If you **need to write cross-edition, cross-version PowerShell code**, the **[`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native)** (`Install-Module Native`; authored by me), has an **`ie`** function (short for: Invoke Executable), which is a polyfill that **provides workaround-free, cross-edition (v3+), cross-platform, cross-version, forward-compatible behavior in the *vast majority* of cases**, both for passing *empty-string* arguments and arguments *with embedded `"` chars. correctly* - simply prepend `ie`  to your external-program calls:

```bash
# With the 'Native' module installed, simply prepending `ie` 
# to your external-program calls ensures that both empty-string
# arguments and arguments with embedded " chars. are passed correctly.
ie python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' '' hi
```

---

<sup>[1] Small caveat: unlike true conditionals, this shortcut performs no *short-circuiting*; that is, *both* array elements are evaluated up front, before the appropriate element is selected by the index expression.</sup>