# How to run multiple commands within git submodule foreach?

Tags: windows, bash, git, foreach, git-submodules

## What I have tried

```
git submodule foreach git checkout main
git submodule foreach git add --all
git submodule foreach git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "%CommitMessage%"
git submodule foreach git push
```

This runs command 1 for all submodules, then command 2 for all submodules, etc.

## What I would like

I would like to only have one foreach, and do all of the commands for a submodule at once, then move on to the next submodule.

## Question

Is there a way to have the `git submodule foreach` call a method, or in some way call multiple commands at once?

I want to do this within a batch script on Windows.

Comment: @Compo, given that the solution requires batch file-specific syntax in order to pass shell commands to `git submodule foreach`, I think the [tag:batch-file] tag is appropriate, and I have restored it.

Comment: The fact that they have used `%CommitMessage%`  and potentially `||` should make absolutely no difference. The question is clear "Is there a way to have the git submodule foreach call a method, or in some way call multiple commands at once?". Batch files are irrelevant to that, and a distraction, or potentially another question after this one has been answered.

Comment: @Compo, the fact that the Unix solution posted below doesn't work from a batch file implies that there _are_ considerations specific to batch files, because the _calling shell and its syntax matter_ when it comes to passing a (POSIX) shell command to `git submodule foreach`. Explicitly spelling out `cmd.exe` / batch-file solutions is important for `git` commands in general, whose sample commands are often written _for POSIX-compatible shells_, but especially when you have a _mix_ of shell syntaxes, as in this case.

Comment: Once the OP has an answer to "a way to have the git submodule foreach call a method, or in some way call multiple commands at once". Then they may have an additional question regarding how that can be implemented within a Windows command line environment or script. There should only be one question per submission, and this one is clear.

Comment: @Compo, I don't think this question is worth answering _in the abstract_, because it is too closely tied to the syntax of the shell a user may be calling from.
Pragmatically speaking, given the limited number of prevalent shells, answers could be given for _all_ of them here, and to a large extent that has already
happened, given that there's also larsks' Bash-focused answer. As such, _both_ `batch-file` and `bash` tags are now appropriate. I have flagged your tag removal for moderator review - nothing personal, I just think the removal was the wrong thing to do.

Comment: As I see it @mklement0, you have over-answered a question, or answered an unasked question, _(by well-founded assumption)_. In doing so you are now arguing for a tag which wasn't relevant until after the fact. You've now included a PowerShell option too, does that mean you're going to argue for its tag to be appended as well. The question already has its full quota of tags, and IMO, the Windows one should adequately cover cmd, powershell and recompiled bash flavors. If anything, my advice would be to replace the 'bash' tag with something more encompassing, perhaps 'command-line-interface'.

Comment: @Compo, yes, I decided to make lemonade - after another answerer had missed the Windows angle - and complete the picture by having this post provide Bash, batch-file, and PowerShell solutions. I originally used the "Windows" tag as a stopgap, given that it is _shells_ that matter here. However, with the addition of the PowerShell solution, "Windows" is now arguably apt, given that both native Windows shells are now covered. I'm happy to leave it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement [larsks' helpful *Unix* solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77157629/45375) (which would also work in Unix-like environments on Windows, such as Git Bash and WSL) with a **solution for *Windows*, from a *batch file*** (see the next section for *PowerShell*):

- As in other cases where `git` supports passing *shell commands*, these are evaluated by Git Bash, i.e the Bash implementation that comes bundled with `git` on Windows. As such, you must use *Bash* (POSIX-compatible) shell syntax even on Windows.
- Note: `git submodule foreach` defines the following (environment) variables to provide information about the submodule at hand, which you may reference in your shell command:

  - `$name`, `$sm_path`,
    `$displaypath`, `$sha1` and `$toplevel`; as noted, due to having to use *Bash* syntax in your shell command, you need to reference these variables as shown (e.g. as `$name` instead of batch-file style `%name%`)
  - See [`git help submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for details.

```bash
git submodule foreach "git checkout main && git add --all && git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m \"%CommitMessage%\" && git push"
```

- Use `"..."` quoting on a *single line* (`cmd.exe` / batch files don't support multiline quoted strings, and programs only expect `"` , not also `'` to have syntactic function on their process command lines).

  - The `%CommitMessage%` batch-style variable reference is expanded *up front*, by `cmd.exe`, `\"...\"` is used to properly escape the embedded `"..."` around the expanded result.
  - **Caveat**: If the value of `%CommitMessage%` contains `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `|` and `&`, the command will *break*, because `cmd.exe` sees these as *unquoted*, due to not understanding that the surrounding `\"` are *escaped* double quotes; as you report, `set "CommitMessage=%info1% | %info2% | %info3%"` caused a problem in your case, and there are two solution options:

    - Either: If feasible, manually `^`-escape the metacharacters; e.g.:

      ```bash
      set "CommitMessage=%info1% ^| %info2% ^| %info3%"
      ```
    - Or, as you have done, use *delayed variable expansion*, which bypasses the problem (but can result in literal `!` characters getting eliminated):

      - Use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the top of your batch file.
      - Then use `!...!` instead of `%...%` to refer to your variable, i.e. `!CommitMessage!`
- Chain the commands with `&&`, so that subsequent commands only execute if the previous ones succeeded.

---

The **PowerShell perspective** (on **both Windows and Unix**-like platforms):

- PowerShell has flexible [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules), including support for *multiline* literals.
- The [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) variant used below helps readability and obviates the need for escaping embedded quotes.

```bash
# NOTE: In Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7.2-,
#       you must manually \-escape the embedded " chars.
#       (... -m \"$CommitMessage\")
#       $CommitMessage is expanded *by PowerShell*, up front.
git submodule foreach @"
  git checkout main && 
  git add --all && 
  git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "$CommitMessage" && 
  git push
"@
```

**Important**:

- As noted in the code comments, Windows PowerShell and [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) versions *up to v7.2.x* unfortunately require embedded `"` chars. to be explicitly `\`-escaped when passing arguments to external programs such as `git`, which is fortunately no longer need in PowerShell (Core) 7.3+

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for more information.
- Because PowerShell too uses sigil `$` for variable references, you must `` ` ``-escape any `$` characters you want to preserve as such, as part of the (POSIX-compatible) shell command to be executed by `git`; e.g., in order to pass verbatim `$name` through in order to refer to the submodule name, use `` `$name ``

  - However, this only necessary if `"..."` quoting is used, i.e an [*expandable* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), which in turn is only necessary if you need PowerShell's *string interpolation* (expansion), such as to embed the value of *PowerShell variable* `$CommitMessage` as shown above.
  - If string interpolation isn't needed, use `'...'` quoting, i.e. a [*verbatim* string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), in which case pass-through `$` chars. need *no* escaping.
- larsks' Unix solution can be used as-is in PowerShell (Core) 7.3+, but only from *Unix*-like environments (including WSL, if you have PowerShell (Core) installed *there* (too)), given that the standard Unix shell, `/bin/sh`, is explicitly called.

  - As an aside: This technique therefore involves an *extra* `sh` process per submodule, but is convenient, because the `-e` option - to abort when a command fails - allows specifying the commands individually, without having to chain them with `&&`

Comment: Good catch, %CommitMessage% was the problem. 

Since it had `|` within it I need to set it like so: `set "CommitMessage=%info1% | %info2% | %info3%"`. I didn't realize that I needed to use `!CommitMessage!` and do `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`.

So the final command was `git submodule foreach "git checkout main && git add --all && git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m \"!CommitMessage!\""`

Note: This is also why I had `\"` to escape the quotes.

Thanks for the help! I am marking your answer as the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Tyler. The alternative to switching to delayed expansion is to use `^`-escaping; please see my update.

Comment: Strangely, if I manually escape using `^` it will work fine for the submodules, but then include the `^` in the message when I am committing to main.

Comment: @Tyler, that is indeed curious. It doesn't happen for me in this minimal example (run from `cmd.exe`, as separate commands): `set "bar=a ^| b"` `echo "foo \"%bar%\" baz"` - you'll see that the echoed string has no `^`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a Unix-like environment, you can run a shell script with `git submodule foreach`:

```
git submodule foreach sh -e -c '
  git checkout main
  git add --all
  git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "message"
  git push
  '
```

Comment: That does not work for me. It ends up running those commands on the parent repo instead. I also get an error about the quotes: `''' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Then you are mistyping something. Here's an example of what running a similar script would look like in a repository with submodules: https://asciinema.org/a/GU0qZkV3fd723w0KhpPc10QFi

Comment: I copied and pasted what you had directly into my batch script

Comment: And yet it demonstrably works, which suggests there is something about your environment which is different. You said "batch script", but this assumes you're running in a Unix shell. Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows, not Unix. Is there a way to do the same thing within Windows?