# Passing multiline parameter to 'dotnet pack' command in PoweShell

Tags: .net, powershell, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, escaping

I'd like to change release notes during `dotnet pack` command. Normally this is straightforward:

```
$releaseNotes = "Something"
dotnet pack --configuration Release -p:PackageReleaseNotes=$releaseNotes
```

But then $releaseNotes variable contains some special characters, multiple lines and otherwise "illegal" symbols i.e.:

````
# Release 2.8.1 - Integrate with Github Actions

- Add Github Actions for build. Remove integration with AppVeyor
- Add architecture tests to check if settings can be properly handled
- Add debuging option for code gen

# Improve TupleHelper
User is no longer required to call for TupleHelper.ParseNext method. It's code was incorporated into ParseElement method. It's now enough to call:
```csharp
var _helper = new TupleHelper(',', '∅', '\\', '(', ')');

var input = "(3.14, Ala ma kota)";
var enumerator = _helper.ParseStart(input, 2, "DoubleAndString");

var key = _helper.ParseElement(ref enumerator, TextTransformer.Default.GetTransformer<double>());
var value = _helper.ParseElement(ref enumerator, TextTransformer.Default.GetTransformer<string>(), 2, "DoubleAndString");

_helper.ParseEnd(ref enumerator, 2, "DoubleAndString");
```
All generated calls were updated accordingly
````

then things go south. How can I force PowerShell to pass proper variables to `-p:PackageReleaseNotes` parameter ?

I tried
`dotnet pack --configuration Release -p:PackageReleaseNotes=$releaseNotes`

and various other forms of command calling including starting command with "&"

The problematic content can be downloaded from (element `body`):
[Github API call](https://api.github.com/repos/nemesissoft/Nemesis.TextParsers/releases/tags/2.8.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Call via `cmd /c` with an [expandable (interpolating) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), which gives you full control over the quoting in the arguments ultimately placed on the target process command line.

  - Specifically, make sure that only the property *value* of the `-p` is enclosed in `"..."`.
- Additionally, *embedded* `"` chars. in  your variable value must be escaped as `\"`

  - `-replace '(?<!\\)(\\*)"', '\$1$1"'` in the code below does that *robustly*; that is, it doubles any preexisting `\` characters that immediately precede an embedded `"`

```bash
# NOTE:
#   In v7.3+, make sure that $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing is at 
#   its default, 'Windows' (or set to 'Legacy')
cmd /c @"
dotnet pack --configuration Release -p:PackageReleaseNotes="$($releaseNotes -replace '(?<!\\)(\\*)"', '\$1$1"')"
"@
```

<sup>Note: To simplify embedded quoting, an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) is used.</sup>

---

###### Background information:

There are two potential problems:

- One problem - ultimately a moot point in the case at hand - is that in *Windows PowerShell* and *[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) up to v7.2.x* you must *manually* `\`-escape embedded `"` characters in arguments passed to external programs.

  - This long-standing problem is fixed in v7.3+, but with *selective exceptions* on Windows - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for details.
  - These exceptions and the fact that the old, broken way of argument-passing applies to them are highly problematic; another problematic aspect is that the list of exceptions may grow over time, sowing confusion over which programs are affected.

    - Case in point: [GitHub issue #18660](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18660#issuecomment-1327870905) asks that `msbuild.exe` be placed on the exception list, due to its specific partial-quoting requirements for property-defining arguments; in fact, it is `msbuild.exe` that `dotnet pack` passes its `-p:` (`/p:`) arguments *through to*, so `dotnet.exe` itself may be another candidate - illustrating the risk of an eternal game of catch-up.
- The other problem is likely that `dotnet` and /or `msbuild.exe` require *very specific, partial quoting* on the process command line (as also discussed in the linked GitHub issue).

  - PowerShell, when it - of necessity - *re-quotes* arguments when it builds the process command line behind the scenes, does *not* preserve partial quoting as originally specified; e.g. `-p:Foo='bar baz'` turns into `"-p:Foo=bar baz"`, i.e. it is *double-quoted as a whole* (and if the argument didn't contain *spaces*, it wouldn't use quoting at all).
  - The solution at the top avoids this problem by calling via `cmd /c`, which offers direct control over quoting.

Comment: I need to run it on GitHub Actions. Since Pwsh is broken, can this problem better be solved via Bash on Linux ?

Comment: @MichałBryłka, in Unix-like environments the problem would indeed not arise, because there are no _process command lines_ there, only _arrays of verbatim arguments_, so all you need to do there is to conform to Bash's syntax. As an - inconsequential - aside: PowerShell is unquestionably broken with respect to passing arguments _with embedded `"`_ to external programs _up to v7.2.x_. Beyond that, the problem is arguably _not_ PowerShell, but those Windows programs that have specific quoting requirements - they shouldn't parse their process command lines _as if they were shells_.