# Can't run test .ps1 as a service from particular directory

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, nssm

I have admin rights on a computer. I have one-liner .ps1 that I create as a service using nssm.exe, and when this ps1 is in `C:\test`, it works. (log on as local system account)

When that same .ps1 resides in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\test`, the service will not run once created. It says it cannot start, but there's nothing in event viewer except that it paused.

Permissions look fine to me. I have full access.

Tried to use `nssm.exe` to create a service for a `.ps1` script, which should let me run the service, but it pauses

Comment: An obvious difference is that path `C:\test` doesn't contain spaces, whereas `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\test` does. Please [edit] your question to show the one-liner content of your `.ps1` file.

Comment: I changed it to progra~1 and it worked, thanks. The weird thing is $File = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshBot\0.12.0\Test-service.ps1"
$Arguments = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile'
& $PSScriptRoot\.\nssm.exe install "Poshbot" $Binary $Arguments -File $File -- I had it all in quotes. I just don't get why it didn't like that

Comment: I've posted an answer with a detailed explanation (which I've amended a few times, but it should be stable and - hopefully - complete now).

Answer (score 0):

**[`nssm.exe`](https://nssm.cc/download)** unfortunately **doesn't preserve the boundaries between pass-through arguments** in its `nssm install` command, and simply space-concatenates the argument values - possibly stripped of syntactic `"` characters - when it writes the service definition to the registry.<sup>[1]</sup>
(By contrast, the argument specifying the *target executable* that will receive the pass-through arguments is properly recognized as a single argument when enclosed in `"..."`; PowerShell does the latter automatically when you pass a variable whose value has embedded spaces.)

While avoiding arguments that contain spaces *bypasses* the problem - such as using the short (8.3) version of a file path - doing so isn't always an option.

For a workaround that does handle arguments with spaces correctly, you must **use *embedded* `"`-quoting** (as part of the argument *value*) in order to pass arguments *with spaces* in a way that what should normally be `"..."` ends up as `\"...\"` on `nssm.exe`'s process command line, which ultimately preserves them as distinct arguments:

*How* that is achieved depends on the PowerShell version you're calling `nssm.exe` from (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for background information):

- When calling from *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.2x*:

  - Embed `\"`
- When calling from *PowerShell 7.3+*:

  - Embed just `"` - PowerShell will take care of passing `\"` on the process command line for you.

In the context of your code, building on your own attempt stated in a comment; works in both PowerShell editions and all (non-obsolete) versions:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Get the PowerShell executable's full path.
$Binary = (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path

# Set the *.ps1 file's full path:
$File = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshBot\0.12.0\Test-service.ps1'

# Install the service and for simplicity pass the 
# the pass-through arguments as a single string, and
# use embedded quoting around arguments that do/may contain spaces.
& $PSScriptRoot\nssm.exe install Poshbot $Binary @"
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File $(("\`"$File\`"", "`"$File`"")[[bool] $IsCoreClr])
"@
```

Note:

- To make using embedded `"` characters easier inside the single arguments string, a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) is used above (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`)
- If you know that you'll be targeting only *Windows PowerShell* (or PowerShell 7.2-) vs. *PowerShell 7.3+*, you can simplify
  `` $(("\`"$File\`"", "`"$File`"")[[bool] $IsCoreClr]) `` to
  `\"$File\"` vs. `"$File"`

---

<sup>[1] Such pass-through arguments are stored in the `AppParameters` value of the `Parameters` subkey of the target service definition, which itself is a subkey of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`</sup>