# How to get a selected file to break down to path and file for robocopy transfer?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am writing a script that opens a file explorer window for any user to select a file to then copy to a preselected machine into a temp folder. I want to be able to select a file anywhere on the machine and break down the path to the file and the file itself for robocopy to then copy it to \WIN10\C$\TEMP however I cannot seem to get it to break down properly.

```
function Copy-FileToMachines {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
        InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
    }

    $result = $fileBrowser.ShowDialog()

    if ($result -eq 'OK') {
        $file = $fileBrowser.SafeFileName
        $source = $fileBrowser.InitialDirectory

        $deviceList = @('Computer1', 'Computer2', 'Computer3')  # Add the names of destination computers here

        foreach ($device in $deviceList) {
            try {
                robocopy "$source" "\\$device\c$\Temp" "$file" /Z /NP /R:3 /W:5 /BYTES /LOG+:`"$env:TEMP\robocopy.log`" | Out-Null
                Write-Host "File successfully copied to $device"
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "An error occurred while copying the file to $device: $_"
            }
        }
  }
```

The above lets me select a file in D:\SOFTWARE but when I read the .log file it shows the source as C:\USERS\ADMINISTRATORS\DESKTOP\

I understand that to be because of InitialDirectory, however I have changed it to Split-Path

```
$file = Split-Path $(FileBrowser.Filename) -Leaf
$source = Split-Path $(FileBrowser.File) -Parent
```

Now when I run it the .log shows the destination of \\WIN10\C$\TEMP as the source now and the file is now showing as **.* in the log.*

What am I missing?

Comment: The `Split-Path` approach would work, but you have typos/syntax errors: use `Split-Path $FileBrowser.Filename -Leaf` and `Split-Path $FileBrowser.Filename -Parent`. Also, `$device:` inside `"..."` would cause a syntax error; use `${device}:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$fileBrowser.FileName` in `Split-Path`. Remove the COLON character after `$device`.

```
function Copy-FileToMachines {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
        InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
    }

    $result = $fileBrowser.ShowDialog()

    if ($result -eq 'OK') {
        $file = $fileBrowser.SafeFileName
        $source = Split-Path -Path $fileBrowser.FileName -Parent     # InitialDirectory

        $deviceList = @('Computer1', 'Computer2', 'Computer3')  # Add the names of destination computers here

        foreach ($device in $deviceList) {
            try {
                robocopy "$source" "\\$device\c$\Temp" "$file" /Z /NP /R:3 /W:5 /BYTES /LOG+:`"$env:TEMP\robocopy.log`" | Out-Null
                Write-Host "File successfully copied to $device"
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "An error occurred while copying the file to $device $_"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot I did remove the ; after $device my apologies but your edit to my work is what got it work! Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasBarry, if you believe this to be the best answer to the question, please select the check mark to the left of the answer. This is how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, [`.InitialDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory#system-windows-forms-filedialog-initialdirectory) is the wrong property to use, because it doesn't reflect the directory path of the file *ultimately selected* by the user.

**[`.FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-forms-filedialog-filename) contains the *full path*** of the selected file, and **splitting it into *directory path* and *file name*** - which your question boils down to - can be achieved in several ways:

- [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) solution, using the ability of the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator to limit the number of tokens *from the end* of the input string, using a *negative* token count:

  ```
  # Note: [\\/] matches both a "\" and a "/", for cross-platform
  #       compatibility.
  $dirPath, $fileName = $fileBrowser.FileName -split '[\\/]', -2
  ```
- *Windows PowerShell* solution (too), using [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path)<sup>[1]</sup> (which is implicitly fcross-platform in PowerShell 7+):

  ```
  $dirPath  = Split-Path $fileBrowser.FileName # -Parent implied
  $fileName = Split-Path -Leaf $fileBrowser.FileName
  ```

  - Alternatively, you can adapt the `-split` solution, although the required [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) is a bit obscure:

    ```
    $dirPath, $fileName = $fileBrowser.FileName -split '[\\/](?=[^\\/]+$)'
    ```

E.g., with `D:\SOFTWARE\file.txt` returned by `$fileBrowser.FileName`, `$dirPath` ends up containing verbatim `D:\SOFTWARE`, and `$fileName` contains `file.txt`.

---

Since I've used different variable names for conceptual clarity, here's your `robocopy` command spelled out, with some improvements:

```
$null = 
  robocopy $dirPath "\\$device\c$\Temp" $fileName /Z /NP /R:3 /W:5 /BYTES /LOG+:$env:TEMP\robocopy.log
```

Note:

- There is *no* need to enclose stand-alone variable references such as `$dirPath` and `$fileName` in `"..."` - just use them as-is.
- Even enclosing `\\$device\c$\Temp` in `"..."` isn't technically necessary here, but is generally advisable in compound arguments, for conceptual clarity and to avoid edge cases.

  - Strictly speaking, the `$` in `c$` should be *escaped* (`` c`$ ``) to prevent interpretation of the `$` as starting a variable reference, as in `$device`; however, if the character following `$` isn't legal as part of a variable name (except if the name as a whole is enclosed in `{...}`), such as `/` here, that isn't necessary.
- By contrast, the *partial* double-quoting you've attempted, `` /LOG+:`"$env:TEMP\robocopy.log`" ``, using *escaped* `"` chars., actually relies on *broken behavior* in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) up to v7.2.x, and would itself break in PowerShell 7.3+, unless you explicitly (temporarily) set `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'` first - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for background information.

  - However, since the value of `$env:TEMP` can be assumed not to contain *spaces*, again no quoting is needed at all, as shown above, or - following the advice in the previous bullet point, by enclosing the whole argument in *unescaped* `"`: `"/LOG+:$env:TEMP\robocopy.log"`; when PowerShell constructs the process command line behind the scenes, it *removes* these `"` in the absence of *embedded spaces* in the value.
- `$null = ...` is used as an alternative to `... | Out-Null` for (stdout) output suppression - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for a discussion of these approaches.

---

As an aside:

- It would be nice if PowerShell provided a way to parse a given path in a manner that returns *all* its constituent parts (drive spec, directory path, file name, base file name, extension) in a *single* operation.
- [GitHub issue #6606](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6606) proposes just that, e.g. in the form of a future `-All` switch to be supported by `Split-Path`, which would return an *object* whose properties reflect the constituent parts.

---

<sup>[1] In this particular case, `Split-Path -Leaf $fileBrowser.FileName` can be replaced with `$fileBrowser.SafeFileName`, given that the - obscurely named - [`.SafeFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename) property contains just the file *name* too.</sup>