# Escape double quotes in a command within multiline string concatenation

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to run psql \copy command from within an Azure DevOps pipeline which is working fine for all my tables but the table where our table name contains dashes: **my-table-name**.

Task script:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Populate data"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        #Setup PostgreSQL
        Set-Service postgresql-x64-14 -StartupType manual
        Start-Service postgresql-x64-14
        Get-CimInstance win32_service | Where-Object Name -eq "postgresql-x64-14"
        #Create tables in PostgreSql database
        $PG_SQL = "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\psql.exe";
        & $PG_SQL -d abcd -U abcd -c "\copy \"my-table-name\" from '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\dump.csv' with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';')";
```

With a hope to achieve (this works when ran within the server):

```
psql -d abcd -U abcd -c "\copy \"my-table-name\" from 'directory\dump.csv' with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';')"
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: COPY  my-table-name FROM STDIN with (format csv,header true...
                ^
```

What I tried:

1. Backtick: `& $PG_SQL -d abcd -U abcd -c "\copy` "my-table-name`" from '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\dump.csv' with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';')";` -> gives above mentioned error
2. Forward slash: `& $PG_SQL -d abcd -U abcd -c "\copy \"my-table-name\" from '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\dump.csv' with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';')";` -> gives above mentioned error
3. Double double quotes: `& $PG_SQL -d abcd -U abcd -c "\copy ""my-table-name"" from '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\dump.csv' with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';')";` -> gives above mentioned error
4. Pre-storing in variable and then surrounding variable with double quotes: `$cpy_cmd = '\copy \"my-table-name\" from D:\a\1\a\my-table-name.csv with (format csv,header true,delimiter \";\")'; & $PG_SQL -d abcd -U abcd -c "$cpy_cmd";` -> works, however here I have to use the static path to the file instead of the cmdlet(is this how I should call it?)

Comment: Would this work? `& $PG_SQL -d "host=<hostname> port=5432 dbname=<dbname> user=<user> sslmode=require password=<password>" -c \copy "my-table-name" from "directory\dump.csv" with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';');`

Comment: no, because the command after -c needs to be a string

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftstorage) tables names cannot contain hypens. Can you rename the table?

Comment: nope, table cannot be renamed (legacy reasons) + the operations on the table work well everywhere but powershell inside yaml. Ofc. my recommendation will always be not to use hyphens in table names

Comment: looks like you might need the backslash for the copy command itself `& $PG_SQL -d abcd -U abcd -c "\copy \""my-table-name\"" from '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\dump.csv' with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';')";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In an ideal world, it would be sufficient to satisfy PowerShell's *own* syntax requirements with respect to embedding `"` characters inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), which means escaping them either as `` `" ``, using PowerShell's general-purpose escape character, the backtick (`` ` ``), or - less commonly - as `""`.
- However, due to a long-standing bug up to at least PowerShell 7.2.4, you must *additionally* `\`-escape such embedded `"` chars in order for *external programs* to see them as such.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details, including information about an experimental feature available in *preview* versions of v7.3, which may fix this problem, possibly on an opt-in basis.

Therefore, *first* escape for PowerShell's sake, and *then* prefix with `\`:

```bash
& $PG_SQL -d abcd -U abcd -c "\copy \`"my-table-name\`" from '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\dump.csv' with (format csv,header true,delimiter ';')";
```