# Can't run icacls to a directory with spaces

Tags: powershell, escaping, icacls

I'm trying to run a simple `icacls` to a directory on my computer and I'm facing this error:

```
PS C:\Users\gguer\Documents> icacls.exe '.\My Digital Editions\'
.\My Digital Editions": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

I'm using single quotes to escape the spaces as I was thought, so I don't know what is the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an explanation to [your own effective workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73255928/45375) (not including a trailing `\` in your argument):

What you're seeing is a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell*** with respect to how it passes arguments to external programs - this problem has been **fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**.

Behind the scenes, **PowerShell (of necessity) translates your *single*-quoted argument containing spaces to a *double*-quoted form,** because external CLIs can only be assumed to understand `"..."` quoting.

The command-line parsing rules used by most CLIs consider the sequence `\"` to be an *escaped* `"` character, i.e. a `"` character to be considered a *verbatim* part of the argument rather than delimiting it.

Therefore, **a verbatim `\` at the *end* of a double-quoted string must itself be escaped as `\\`** in order to be recognized as such - ***this is what Windows PowerShell neglects to do***:

That is, Windows PowerShell translates your call as follows:

```bash
# Resulting command line as used behind the scenes for actual invocation.
# WinPS: BROKEN, because the \ at the end isn't escaped.
icacls.exe ".\My Digital Editions\"
```

When `icacls.exe` parses this command line, it sees verbatim `.\My Digital Editions"` (note the verbatim `"` at the end), as reflected in the error message.

PowerShell (Core), by contrast, does perform the necessary escaping:

```bash
# Resulting command line as used behind the scenes for actual invocation.
# PowerShell (Core): OK
icacls.exe ".\My Digital Editions\\"
```

---

**Workarounds**:

- In a *literal* path, simply omit a trailing `\` - which won't work for a *root* path, however, and it also assumes that this doesn't change the meaning of the argument from the target program's perspective (it doesn't for `icacls.exe`).

  - *Programmatic* solution:

    ```bash
    $path = '.\My Digital Editions\'
    icacls.exe $path.TrimEnd('\')  # !! Doesn't work for ROOT paths, e.g. "C:\"
    ```
- Alternatively - which also works for root paths - *manually* double the trailing `\`

  - *Quick-and-dirty* programmatic solution, knowing that file-system paths may contain duplicated `\` separators without ill-effects (however, it may affect path *comparisons*):

    ```bash
    icacls.exe "$path\"
    ```
- A *robust, cross-edition* programmatic solution that doesn't modify the argument is a bit more cumbersome:

  ```bash
  icacls.exe $(if ($path.EndsWith('\') -and $PSVersionTable.PSEdition -ne 'Core') { "$path\" } else { $path })
  ```

---

As an aside:

A **related bug** that affects how **`"`** (double quotes) embedded in arguments are passed to external programs is affects PowerShell (Core) up to 7.2.x - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Just had to remove the last backslash. Cheers.