# windows powershell findstr incorrect behaviour

Tags: powershell, findstr

I am looking for a search string inside a json file:

```
> type .\input.json
[
    {"name": "moish"},
    {"name": "oren"}
]
> type .\input.json | findstr /n /l "\`"name\`": \`"or"
2:    {"name": "moish"},
3:    {"name": "oren"}
```

How come `moish` entry is found? what am I missing?

Comment: Your complicated string is interpreted as two separate search patterns rather than one, so it will match anything that includes `"name"`. I see no reason not to use PowerShell's `Select-String` instead: `| Select-String '"name": "or' | select LineNumber, Line`. Also consider `ConvertFrom-Json` so you can treat the input as objects, which simplifies searching for escaped strings.

Comment: Good points, @JeroenMostert. To make `findstr` treat the string as a _single_ pattern, it must be prefixed with `/c:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The quoted lines below, originally a direct part of the answer, turned out *not* to apply to the problem at hand, because the escaping in the question is correct (the only thing missing was placing `/c:` directly before the string to make `findstr.exe` search for it *as a whole*).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709152/712649) for a more comprehensive analysis of the problem.

> Escape the literal quotation marks by doubling them:

> ```
> type input.json |findstr /n /l """name"": ""or"
> ```

> ... or use single-quotes to qualify the search term:

> ```
> type input.json |findstr /n /l '"name": "or'
> ```

.... or perhaps use the native PowerShell cmdlet `Select-String` instead of `findstr`:

```
Select-String -LiteralPath input.json -Pattern '"name": "or'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Prepend `/c:` to your search string** in order to make [`findstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) treat it as **a *single* string to search for**:

```bash
Get-Content .\input.json | findstr /n /l /c:"\`"name\`": \`"or" # Note the /c:
```

<sup>Note the use of the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet for reading a file line by line, which `type` is a built-in alias for in PowerShell.</sup>

Note:

- By default, if a search string contains spaces, `findstr` searches for the occurrence of *any* of the space-separated words, i.e., `"name"` *or* `"or`, causing *both* lines to match. `/c:` signals that the string *as a whole string* should be searched for (either as a regular expression, by default, or as a literal string, with `/l`)
- Except for the missing `/c:`, your search string was correct, but you could have simplified by using a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings):

  - `... | findstr /n /l /c:'\"name\": \"or'`
  - Sadly, the *additional* `\`-escaping of the embedded `"` chars. is a requirement either way, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x, even though it *shouldn't be necessary*.

    - It is due to a long-standing bug in how PowerShell passes arguments with embedded double-quotes to *external programs*; a - possibly opt-in - fix *may* be coming - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).
    - *If* you're using a 7.2.x version or a 7.3 *preview* version of PowerShell with the [*experimental* feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features) named `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` enabled *and* the `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` preference variable set to either `'Standard'` or `'Windows'`, the `\`-escaping is no longer needed, because PowerShell then (finally) does it for you; that is, `findstr /n /l /c:'"name": "or'` would suffice.

---

**PowerShell alternative: `Select-String`:**

As shown in [Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73700496/45375), you may alternatively use the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet, the more powerful PowerShell counterpart to `findstr.exe`, not least to **avoid quoting headaches (see above) and potential character-encoding issues**.

- Like `findstr.exe`, `Select-String` uses *regular expressions* by default; use `-SimpleMatch` to opt for literal matching.
- Unlike `findstre.exe`, `Select-String` is case-*insensitive* by default (as PowerShell generally is). Use `-CaseSensitive` to make matching case-sensitive.
- `Select-String` wraps matching lines in *objects* that include metadata about each match; if you're interested in the line text only, use `-Raw` in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, or pipe to `ForEach-Object Line` in *Windows PowerShell*.
- While piping lines read from a file via `Get-Content` works, it is much slower than the passing the file *path* as an argument directly to `Select-String`, via its `-LiteralPath` parameter (you may also pipe file-info objects obtained with `Get-ChildItem` to it).

  - This has the added advantage that the display representation of the matching lines includes the file name an line number (see below).

Thus, the equivalent of your (corrected) `findstr.exe` call is:

```bash
Select-String -LiteralPath .\input.json -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch -Pattern '"name": "or'

# Alternative:
Get-ChildItem .\input.json |
  Select-String -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch -Pattern '"name": "or'
```

You'll get the following output in the console (note the output-line prefix consisting of the file name and the line number):

```
input.json:3:  {"name": "oren"}
```

Note that this is the for-display representation of the *object* of type [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) that `Select-String` emitted for the matching line.

Comment: wow thank you very much for the detailed answer - I learned a lot !