# Pass variable string command to powershell -Command

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to run this command, which is read from another script.

```
$command = "$arr = @($input)
$arr.count
Write-Host $arr[0]"

"Classical Music for When You are on a Deadline." | & cmd /C powershell -Command {$command}
```

So I am getting something through the pipe and then I use it in my string command. The code does not work because `$command` is not expanded to the string inside the call and therefore unknown in the launched powershell command.

These work as expected, but the commands are not taken from a string:

```
"Classical Music for When You are on a Deadline." | & cmd /C powershell -Command {Invoke-Expression "Write-Host $input"}

# No:   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineReader`1+<GetReadEnumerator>d__20[System.Object]
# "Classical Music for When You are on a Deadline." | & cmd /C powershell -Command {Write-Host $input}

"Classical Music for When You are on a Deadline." | & cmd /C powershell -Command {$arr = @($input)
    $arr.count
    Write-Host $arr[0]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `{ $command }` does *not* turn the value of string `$command` into  a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) - it simply creates a script block that references a variable named `$command`.

  - To **create a script block from a string**, use **[`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create)**
- Also, do *not* call `powershell.exe` via `cmd /c` - it is generally unnecessary.

Therefore:

```bash
$command = '$arr = @($input)
$arr.count
Write-Host $arr[0]'

"Classical Music for When You are on a Deadline." | 
  powershell ([scriptblock]::Create($command))  # -Command is implied.
```

Note:

- The above is the dynamic, variable-based equivalent of the last solution attempt in your question.
- Using a *script block* rather than a *string* with PowerShell's CLI - which is only an option from *inside* PowerShell - is generally preferable, for the following reasons:

  - *Limited type fidelity* is provided, using the same XML-based serialization infrastructure as for background jobs and remoting; that is, you can return objects *other than strings* from such a CLI call; similarly, such calls preserve *all* of PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
  - Base64-encoding is used behind the scenes to safely pass the script block's source code to the target PowerShell process, which bypasses any quoting and escaping headaches.

    - Notably, due to a long-standing bug up to PowerShell 7.2.x, passing commands *as string* requires embedded `"` characters to be *manually escaped as* `\"` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

In other words: While `powershell -Command $command` would have worked *with the specific sample string*, it would fail if the string  contained `"` characters, invariably in Windows PowerShell, and up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x.

---

Taking a step back: Since **you're already running in PowerShell, there is no need to create *another* instance**, as a *child process*, which is expensive.

```bash
$command = '$arr = @($input)
$arr.count
Write-Host $arr[0]'

# Invoke the dynamically created script block directly.
"Classical Music for When You are on a Deadline." | 
  & ([scriptblock]::Create($command))
```

Note:

- `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) is used to invoke the script block, which runs it in a *child* scope.

  - If you want the script block to run directly in the caller's scope, use `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) instead.
- `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) - which should [generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) - is *not* an option here anyway, because it doesn't support using the pipeline to pass data to the code being evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon: it would, but only if `$command` happens to contain _no embedded `"` characters_  - I've updated the answer to make that clear.

Comment: I see what you mean, if calling from pwsh works ok using a here-string tho it fails when calling from powershell

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, no, unless you happen to be on v7.3.0 specifically, it won't work from `pwsh` either - and it looks like the v7.3.0 fix will be reverted and become _opt-in_ in v7.3.1+ - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18694

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't tell the whole story: `cmd /c` is mandatory because that's what the (missing here) final command is expecting. My bad, OTOH, the first solution works very well for me with `cmd /C powershell`, so your generous answer solves my specific problem, while covering a more generic problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Invoke-Expression cmdlet to run a variable string as a command in PowerShell. For example:
`Invoke-Expression $commandString`

Comment: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375), which is always worth mentioning. While a security risk is inherent in the scenario at hand - execution of a command stored in a string received from an outside source - a solution without `Invoke-Expression` is still possible and preferable in this case.