# Pass Arguments to Start-Process with spaces

Tags: powershell

I would like to pass the powershell arguments to an process. The arguments may contain spaces.

Powershell Code:

```
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath "wsl.exe" -ArgumentList $args -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$proc | Wait-Process
```

Run Command

```
powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file sh.ps1 bash -c "`"echo Hello World`""
```

No Output.

---

Running this command with static array works fine:

```
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath "wsl.exe" -ArgumentList @("bash", "-c", "`"echo Hello World`"") -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$proc | Wait-Process
```

Output

```
Hello World
```

---

What I needed todo to escape the arguments from the CLI args?

See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576 why I have to escape spaces

Comment: As aside, do not use `$args` as self-defined variable because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#args). Choose another name for that

Comment: You do not need to escape the string since it is not inside another string.  So use : powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file sh.ps1 bash -c "echo Hello World"

Comment: Why use start-process at all? `wsl bash -c 'echo hello world'` The arguments probably need to be an array.

Comment: In the case of bash, you can also run it directly:  `bash -c 'echo hello world'`  You can also install the linux pwsh.

Comment: @Theo thats the use case, I want to pass arguments from CLI. I do not define $args by myself.

Comment: @jdweng It do not work. Tested from windows powershell. Arguments are not correctly passed to Start-Process. - See also https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576

Comment: @js2010 It's windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good reason to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) in your case (see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) for guidance on when `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate).

Instead, **use *direct execution***, which is not only synchronous and runs in the same console window (for *console* applications such as `wsl.exe`), but also allows you to directly capture or redirect output.

In doing so, you'll also be *bypassing* the longstanding `Start-Process` bug you mention ([GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576)), because PowerShell double-quotes arguments passed to external programs *as needed* behind the scenes (namely if they contain spaces).

```bash
$exe, $exeArgs = $args   # split argument array into exe and pass-thru args
wsl.exe -e $exe $exeArgs # execute synchronously, via wsl -e
```

Note that you then also don't need to *embed* escaped `"` in your PowerShell CLI call:

```bash
powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file sh.ps1 bash -c "echo Hello World"
```

However, if your arguments truly needed embedded `"`, you'd run into another longstanding PowerShell bug that affects only *direct* invocation of external programs, necessitating *manual* escaping with `\` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

---

**If you *do* need to use `Start-Process`** - e.g. if you want the process to run in a *new (console) window* - you'll have to provide *embedded* quoting around those `$args` elements that need it, along the following lines:

```bash
$quotedArgs = foreach ($arg in $args) {
  if ($arg -notmatch '[ "]') { $arg }
  else { # must double-quote
    '"{0}"' -f ($arg -replace '"', '\"' -replace '\\$', '\\')
  }
}

$proc = Start-Process -FilePath "wsl.exe" -ArgumentList $quotedArgs -PassThru
$proc | Wait-Process
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is this, with $myargs being an array of strings.  "echo Hello World" needs embedded double-quotes (or single-quotes) around it, which complicates things.

```
$myargs = "bash", "-c", "'echo Hello World'"
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath wsl.exe -ArgumentList $myargs -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$proc | Wait-Process

Hello World
```

I would just do:

```
.\sh.ps1 bash -c 'echo hello world'

# sh.ps1 contains:
# wsl $args
```

Or the wsl bash for windows:

```
bash -c 'echo hello world'
```

I happened to have pwsh installed within wsl.  Without the single-quotes, each word would be put on a new line.

```
wsl pwsh -c "echo 'hello world'"
```

This works for me within another powershell, with yet another set of embedded quotes:

```
powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file sh.ps1 bash -c "`"'echo Hello World'`""
```

Comment: I do not define `$args` by myself, it comes from Powershell itself. Just `& $shell @args` doesn't work, too.

Comment: @jkroepke Where is powershell.exe running *from*?

Comment: For testing, from an interactive powershell. Later is running from a go programm. But it is the behaivor