# sed tool unable to convert CRLF to LF in Windows powershell bash

Tags: bash, powershell, sed, replace, newline

I have a file with CRLF line endings, which I need to convert to LF. This sed command can do that: `sed -E -i "s/\r\n/\n/" file.txt`.

I have sed installed in my Windows 11 using msys2. So, if I execute the above sed command in Powershell, it executes successfully and converts CRLF to LF.

But instead, if I execute the above sed command inside bash in Powershell, it completes with no output to the console. But it fails to convert CRLF to LF.

Instead if I run a sed command to word character replacement, it executes correctly both in Powershell and Powershell bash. So I think this has something to do with how CRLF is handles by bash.

So now, how to convert CRLF to LF in Powershell bash using sed?

Comment: @mklement0 I guess it is the Bash provided by WSL. I'm using `bash` command to switch to a bash terminal. Then pasting the exact sed command given above.

Comment: try `sed -E -i 's/\r\n/\n/' file.txt` .(with single-quotes).  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter no luck :(

Comment: It has been a long time since I've done this.  Probably 25 years.  My solution was "s/$/\r/"

Comment: @jdweng, your command does the opposite of what the question asks for.

Comment: I was going back and forth between unix and windows.  Got direction backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command in your WSL `bash` session in order to perform in-place conversion of a file from `\r\n` (CRLF, Windows-format) to `\n` (LF, Unix-format) newlines (line endings):<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
sed -i 's/\r$//' file.txt
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind reading the file *as a whole*, using GNU `sed`'s `-z` option and the `g` regex option for *global* matching (finding *all* matches):

```bash
sed -i -z 's/\r\n/\n/g' file.txt
```

---

Your problem was unrelated to PowerShell; instead, there was a **problem with the logic of your `sed` command**:

- **`sed` reads input *line by line* by default**, and *removes* the trailing newline from each.

  - Therefore, ***no* line that a `sed` script operates on contains `\n`** by default, so a substitution (`s` command) trying to match `\r\n` is invariably a *no-op*.
- Because `sed` considers *only* `\n` (LF) *alone* a newline:

  - Those lines originally terminated with `\r\n` will *end in* `\r` (CR) when a `sed` operation is performed on them.
- `s/\r$//` therefore removes that trailing `\r` from each line, and - on writing the modified lines back to the file - terminates each line with *just* `\n`, so that in effect only `\n` (LF) newlines remain.

---

Note:

- The only reason **why `sed -E -i "s/\r\n/\n/" file.txt` worked for you** is that the **`sed` implementation that comes with MSYS has *special behavior for Windows***:

  - On *reading* files, it recognizes *both* `\n` (LF) *and* `\r\n` (CRLF) as newlines.
  - On *writing* files, it *only* uses `\n` (LF)
  - As such, it converts CRLF sequences to LF *by default*, and the following command would suffice, i.e. providing an *empty script*:

    - `sed -i ' ' file.txt`

      - Note: `sed -i '' file.xt` *should* work, i.e. passing an *empty string* as the script argument, but doesn't up to PowerShell 7.2.x, due to a long-standing bug that accidentally *removes* empty-string arguments when calling *external programs* - see [GitHub issue #6280](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6280) for details.
        The underlying cause of this bug more prominently manifests in the inability to pass arguments *with embedded `"` chars.* to external programs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).
  - For the reasons explained above, `s/\r\n/\n/` actually has *no* effect - in *any* `sed` implementation. In other words: **it was simply the *default* behavior of the MSYS `sed` implementation that happened to perform the desired conversion for you**.

---

<sup>[1] To perform the ***opposite* conversion** - from LF-only to CRLF newlines, use `sed -i 's/$/\r/' file.txt`, as [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) notes.</sup>

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB, please see my update re using the `-z` option.