# Using PowerShell To Create Scheduled Task With Spaces

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, quotes

I have two script to use as part of an application install.  The first script creates a scheduled task to run the second script after the server reboots.  That portion of the script is:

```
$installScript = "$PSScriptRoot\Install.ps1"
schtasks.exe /CREATE /F /TN "Install Application" /RU $taskUser /SC ONLOGON /IT /TR "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $installScript" /RL HIGHEST
```

This has worked really well for me, but I just discovered a hitch.  When `$PSScriptRoot` has spaces in it, the scheduled task fails to find the Install.ps1 script.  I've found if I edit the argument in the scheduled task to include "" around the path, it works without issue.  But I'm not sure how to accomplish that.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the command that `powershell.exe` sees on invocation with `-File`, the value of `$installScript` must be *enclosed in `"..."`* (double quotes) for script paths that contain spaces (or other PowerShell metacharacters, such as `{`).
- Since you're relying on outer `"..."` quoting in order to *expand* (interpolate) the value of `$installScript`, you must therefore *escape* the *embedded* `"` characters you need to enclose `$installScript` in.

  - `` `" `` (or `""`) must be used for escaping; e.g.:

    - `` "Nat `"King`" Cole" `` results in *verbatim* `Nat "King" Cole`
  - See the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.
- Unfortunately, because you're calling an *external program* (`schtasks.exe`), and *additional* escaping requirement comes into play, due to a long-standing bug:

  - Up to PowerShell 7.2.x, you must *manually* `\`-escape `"` chars. that the target program should (also) see as escaped ones.
  - With selective exceptions on Windows, this problem has been fixed in PowerShell 7.3+.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for more information.

Therefore, you must *combine* these two escaping mechanisms in your case, which **requires enclosing `$installScript` in `` \`" ``** (sic), i.e. `` \`"$installScript"\`" ``:

```
# Note: The \-escaping is no longer needed in PS 7.3+
$installScript = "$PSScriptRoot\Install.ps1"
schtasks.exe /CREATE /F /TN "Install Application" /RU $taskUser /SC ONLOGON /IT /TR "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \`"$installScript\`"" /RL HIGHEST
```