# Using Vim's Terminal JSON API From pwsh / windows terminal

Tags: powershell, vim, windows-terminal

For when you are in Vim's `:terminal` buffer, and you want to open a new file, but use the existing Vim instance instead of create a new one, Vim has a specific escape sequence you can enter to tell Vim to do a command like open a file:

```
Job to Vim: JSON API ~
                            *terminal-api*
The job can send JSON to Vim, using a special escape sequence.  The JSON
encodes a command that Vim understands.  Example of such a message:
    <Esc>]51;["drop", "README.md"]<07>
```

But how do I enter these characters in windows terminal / pwsh?

Looks like I *can* use the api successfully from zsh (WSL) via the following:

```
 printf '\033]51;["drop", "README.md"]\07'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're seeing an **apparent limitation in the native *Windows* version of Vim (`vim.exe`) due to the specifics of Windows' VT (Virtual Terminal) support** - and the limitation applies irrespective of whether you launch `vim.exe` stand-alone, from a `conhost.exe` window (regular console window), or from Windows Terminal:

  - The **Job-to-Vim terminal escape sequence** you mention (as documented [here](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html)) **is *quietly ignored***.
  - Technically, due to starting with `<ESC>]`, the escape sequence at hand is of type [*OSC* (Operating System Command)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC), specifically with parameter `51`; on the Windows API side - the VT (Virtual Terminal) support in console windows - at least *some* of those OSC sequences are supported, as implied by the statements in [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#window-title):

    - However, the OSC examples there are handled *by the console itself* (e.g., setting the window title).
    - *As you've discovered yourself*:

      - [XTerm defines the OSC with parameter `51` as reserved for Emacs](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands), which Vim apparently chose to use also.
    - **It seems that [Windows' VT support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) doesn't pass this specific  OSC through to Vim**; it may be worth opening an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues.
- By contrast, **the Job-to-Vim escape sequence *does* work on Unix-like platforms**, including when running Vim from inside WSL on Windows (`/usr/bin/vim`).

The following describes how to emit such an escape sequence from PowerShell *in principle*, but for the reasons stated, it won't solve your problem in Windows Terminal /  Windows console windows.

---

In PowerShell (Core) 7.3+, from a *Unix* environment,

```
printf '\033]51;["drop", "README.md"]\07'
```

should work as-is.

(In v7.2-, due to a long-standing bug, you'll have to escape the `"` chars. as `\"` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)).

---

The PowerShell-native v7+ equivalent - which works on *all* platforms - is (see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic):

```
Write-Host -NoNewLine "`e]51;[`"drop`", `"README.md`"]`a"
```

(In *Windows PowerShell*, escape sequence `` `e `` to produce an ESC char. isn't supported; use `$([char] 27)` instead.)

Note that `` "`e]51;[`"drop`", `"README.md`"]`a" `` *alone*, using PowerShell's *implicit* output mechanism, would implicitly print a *newline* after the string value, hence the use of `Write-Host -NoNewLine` (alternatively, use `[Console]::Write(...)`)

Comment: The PowerShell-native v7+ command is close to what I've been trying, but without luck. I'm starting in winterm/pwsh, then `vim`, then `:term`, then executing the above. I'm on pwsh 7.3.4. I've also tried piping it to `out-string` or setting `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'ANSI'`, because of [these docs on ANSI escape code support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.3) but without luck. I get a blank line printed and nothing from vim.

Comment: @xdhmoore, does ``[Console]::Write("`e]51;[`"drop`", `"README.md`"]`a")`` make a difference?

Comment: the only difference I see - the command from your original post above leaves an empty line before the next prompt, but the `[Console]` command does not. the prompt prints on the next line.

Comment: best I can tell, ignoring unknown OSC commands is [the usual VT100 behavior](https://vt100.net/emu/dec_ansi_parser), but xterm [has a special OSC 51 command for passthru to Emacs](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), which would explain why vim chose that sequence. I'm not sure I care enough to open an issue for it with win terminal, but I think this is indeed the problem.