# Exporting a PostgreSQL table via command line: how to escape double quotes

Tags: powershell, psql, windows-terminal

I'm trying to use the `psql` command line on a Windows 11 machine to export the results of a query from a `PostgreSQL 15` database to a CSV file.

The problem I am facing is that the query in question is this:

```
SELECT * FROM "MyTable"
```

but while this works fine when run via pgAdmin, if I run the following command line (connection parameters omitted for brevity):

```
./psql.exe -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM MyTable) TO 'c:/out.csv'"
```

I get an error saying:

> ERROR:  relationship "mytable" does not exist
> ROW 1: COPY (SELECT * FROM MyTable) TO 'c:/out.csv'

I suspect that the problem might be that I'm not using the double quotes " around the table name, because if I run the query in pgAdmin without the double quotes I get the exact same error.
But how do I put the double quotes in the command line? In the windows cmd/powershell command line the double quotes are argument value delimiters, so if I use them INSIDE the argument value it just truncates it.

I've tried using double quotes `""` or the tick  `` `" `` to escape it following some suggestions I've found online, but the error message never changes. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: I know I can launch PSQL in interactive shell mode and issue the command from there, but this is no good to me because this command is part of a script, I don't want it to be interactive, I want it to just execute and return to the command line.

Comment: `""` should work fine in Windows cmd. What do you get when you do `./psql.exe -c "select current_database(), current_user, current_setting('search_path');"`?

Comment: @Zegarek: thanks for the reply. You're correct, it works with the double " in cmd, the problem was that I was testing on the windows terminal/powershell. Any idea how to escape it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to swap the internal single quotes `'` for [double-dollar quotes `$$`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING), which releases the [string constant single quotes `'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) to be used as outer quotes, and [double-quotes for delimited identifier `"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), which can simplify things.

In PowerShell you won't need the backtick `` ` `` to protect the `$` because [single-quoted strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#single-quoted-strings) are verbatim, already preventing their evaluation. As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77459602/exporting-a-postgresql-table-via-command-line-how-to-escape-double-quotes/77459741?noredirect=1#comment136557873_77459741) by [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) below, what you will need in [PS version <7.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/5298879) is a backslash to let the parameter hold onto the double-quotes:

```sh
./psql.exe -c 'COPY \"MyTable\" TO $a$c:/out.csv$a$ CSV HEADER'
```

As an alternative to `$$`, you can double the single quotes around file name:

```sh
./psql.exe -c 'COPY \"MyTable\" TO ''c:/out.csv'' CSV HEADER'
```

Double-double-quoting should also work, but the backslash requirement complicates it a bit:

```sh
./psql.exe -c "COPY \""MyTable\"" TO 'c:/out.csv' CSV HEADER"
```

Note that regular `COPY` happens server-side. `psql` offers client-side [meta-command `\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY):

```sh
./psql.exe -c "\copy \""MyTable\"" TO 'c:/out.csv' CSV HEADER"
```

or trade `psql` for [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), if you're fine with a `.sql` or custom dump instead of a `.csv`

```sh
./pg_dump.exe -t '\"MyTable\"' -f 'c:/MyTable_dump'
```

In `cmd`, single outer quotes won't work, but double quotes on the inside work fine:

```sh
./psql.exe -c "\copy ""MyTable"" TO 'c:/out.csv' CSV HEADER"
```

If you're copying all columns and rows of the entire table, you can give both versions of `copy` its name directly, instead of the `(select * from "MyTable")` or `(table "MyTable")`. Parenthesized syntax is more useful for queries with some additional complexity.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you.