# Psexec issue with variable command in Powershell

Tags: powershell, psexec

I'm looking to automate the use of Psexec through a Powershell script. The aim is to send mass commands to a list of servers. So far, nothing extraordinary when you know the possibilities of Psexec. The problem arises when I want to put the command to be executed on the remote machines in a variable. As soon as the command has a space, it cannot be executed on the remote machine and I get the error : The specified path cannot be found. I've tried putting my variable between "" or '' or `` but nothing changes.

In the script, this command works fine :

```
PsExec.exe \\$SelectedServerIP -u my_user -p my_password ipconfig /all
```

but these one don't work :

```
$command = "ipconfig /all"
PsExec.exe \\$SelectedServerIP -u my_user -p my_password $command

$command = "ipconfig /all"
PsExec.exe \\$SelectedServerIP -u my_user -p my_password ""$command""

$command = ipconfig /all
PsExec.exe \\$SelectedServerIP -u my_user -p my_password ""$command""

$command = ipconfig /all
PsExec.exe \\$SelectedServerIP -u my_user -p my_password """$command"""
```

Thank you for your answers.

LG

Answer (score 0):

[`psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) expects the command line to be executed remotely to be specified as *individual arguments* rather than a *single string*.

Thus, use an [*array*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) to programmatically define these arguments:

```bash
# The following is equivalent to:
#   PsExec.exe \\$SelectedServerIP -u my_user -p my_password ipconfig /all
$command = @('ipconfig', '/all')
PsExec.exe \\$SelectedServerIP -u my_user -p my_password $command
```

Note:

- When an array is passed to an *external program*, PowerShell automatically passes its elements as individual arguments; in other words: it *implicitly* performs [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting); for conceptual clarity you could choose to use splatting explicitly, however, by passing `@command` instead of `$command`.
- However, there is a *quoting caveat*, and it applies to *all* external programs, not just `psexec`:

  - The sad reality in *Windows PowerShell* and in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.2.x* is that an *extra, manual* layer of `\`-escaping of *embedded `"` characters* is required in arguments passed to *external programs*. This is fixed in PowerShell *v7.3+*, with selective exceptions on Windows. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details.
  - A quick example (run from an elevated session):

    ```bash
    # OK in v7.3+ only, because only there are the 
    # embedded " chars. properly passed.
    # Should print: hi there
    $command = @('powershell', '-noprofile', '"hi there"')
    psexec -s $command

    # Solution for v7.2- and Windows PowerShell:
    # Manual `\`-escaping.
    $command = @('powershell', '-noprofile', '\"hi there\"')
    psexec -s $command
    ```

Comment: Thank you, it does indeed work.
I had a second problem entering the order through a textbox. I had to split the text in the textbox before sending the command and it works now.