# PHP Array to Powershell exec Command Args

Tags: php, arrays, powershell

I'm currently building a little app to retrieve information from an HTML Form (multiples checkboxes actually) and pass this information as args to a powershell exec command.

Currently I get this kind of array as a result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Group1
    [1] => Group2
    [2] => Group3
    [3] => Group4
    [4] => Group5
    [5] => Group6
)
```

At first I wanted to put this array in a CSV file and then read this CSV from the powershell script but I wonder if there is a way to use this array directly in my shell_exec as an arg (powershell formatted array @("Group1","Group2")

My php (where $arg2 is the above array):

```
<?php
$Psscript = "C:\Scripts\script.ps1";
$arg1 = $_POST["data1"];
$arg2 = $_POST["data2"];
echo '<pre>'; print_r($arg2); echo '</pre>';

shell_exec("powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command $Psscript $arg1 $arg2");
?>
```

Has anybody succeeded in making thing like this work ?

Thank you for any suggestions and please don't hesitate to ask if you need more information ;)

Edit : Current php

```
$Psscript = "C:\Scripts\script.ps1";

$arg1 = $_POST["arg1"];
$arg2 = $_POST["arg2"];
$groups = '@("'. implode('","', $_POST["groups"]) .'")';

echo $groups;

$result = shell_exec("powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command $Psscript $arg1 $arg2 $groups 2>&1");
echo $result;
}
?>
```

Powershell :

```
###### Args ######
$arg1 = $args[0];
$arg2 = $args[1];
$groups = $args[2];
$fullname = "$arg1.$arg2"

if (!($session)) {$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'srv01' -ConfigurationName "Microsoft.PowerShell32" -Credential $cred}

    Invoke-Command -Session $sessionAD -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    foreach ($group in $using:groups)
    {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "$group" -Members "$using:fullname"
    }
    }

Remove-PSSession $sessionAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) plus a bit of string concatenation on either end you can fairly easily produce the format you specified, ready for insertion into the powershell command string:

```
$arg2 = array
(
    0 => "Group1",
    1 => "Group2",
    2 => "Group3",
    3 => "Group4",
    4 => "Group5",
    5 => "Group6"
);

echo '@("'.implode('","', $arg2).'")';
```

outputs:

```
@("Group1","Group2","Group3","Group4","Group5","Group6")
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/lhn38

Comment: Thanks, yes this is looking good. My powershell script works well on standalone when I put the array as arg but not when I'm passing it through php with shell_exec and I need now to figure out why.

Comment: @Ben74 are you checking the final string you are submitting to Powershell from PHP, to ensure it exactly matches what you are sending manually? Also you should get the output _from_ shell_exec in case it gives any errors etc - at the moment your code isn't doing that. You should do something like `$cmd = "powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command $Psscript $arg1 $arg2"; var_dump($cmd); $output = shell_exec($cmd); var_dump($output);` so you can see precisely what is passed to powershell and what is returned.

Comment: https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP if you're not familiar with the concept in general.

Comment: Ok seems like when passing the string @("Group1","Group2") to powershell, it removes the "" ==>  @("Group1","Group2") becomes @(Group1,Group2)

Comment: @Ben74 Not sure how that's happened? It should work - demo: https://3v4l.org/uBkDj . Can you provide your current code?

Comment: It's good on php's side, the return on powershell's side is telling me there is missing "" At line:1 char:61 + C:\Scripts\Psscript.ps1 test test @(Group1,Group2 ... + ~ Missing argument in parameter list. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to the same kind of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036580/pwsh-command-is-removing-quotation-marks

Comment: @Ben74 `C:\Scripts\Psscript.ps1 test test @(G`...why is `test` in there twice? Looks like that would be treated as a separate argument?

Comment: I actually have one more argument. I simplified my question earlier.

Comment: @Ben74 ok. Always better to show us your real code (especially when it's as trivial as that), then there's no confusion later on :-)

Comment: I added my current code in the initial post ;)

Comment: solve using escape \ before the quotations marks to keep them in powershell : $groups = '@(\"'. implode('\",\"', $_POST["groups"]) .'\")';

Answer (score 1):

This: `$arg2 = '@("'. implode('","', $_POST["data2"]) .'"))';`
Would generate a string like this:
`@("Group1","Group2","Group3","Group4","Group5","Group6"))`

Comment: Thanks, working minus a ")" at the end ;)

Comment: Yeah, I just copied the sample, never have i ever used an array in powershell so ...